# Regex - Operador "." - Captura de meta caracter

Tags: php, regex

#### Situação

Estou realizando um pesquisa com `regex` em uma palavra específica **`inválido`**, mas por preferência decidi usar **`inv.lido`**. A qual eu sabia que tinha na string teste, mas não retornou.

#### Testes

`vr` = `var_dump`
`pr` = `print_r`

```
$string = 'até, atenção, Hipótese, você, português, café, órgão';

vr(preg_match('~at.~', $string, $match));
pr($match);
vr(preg_match('~aten..o~', $string, $match));
pr($match);
vr(preg_match('~Hip.tese~', $string, $match));
pr($match);
vr(preg_match('~voc.~', $string, $match));
pr($match);
vr(preg_match('~portugu.s~', $string, $match));
pr($match);
vr(preg_match('~caf.~', $string, $match));
pr($match);
vr(preg_match('~.rg.o~', $string, $match));
pr($match);
```

#### Out

```
int(1)
Array([0] => at�)

int(0)
Array()

int(0)
Array()

int(1)
Array([0] => voc�)

int(0)
Array()

int(1)
Array([0] => caf�)

int(0)
Array()
```

#### Questão

Como podem ver ele não capturou as palavras, exceto algumas, contudo mesmo as que ele capturou, eu não sei o que é o `�`, pois mesmo usando `utf8_decode` ou mesmo `utf8_encode` ele não me retorna o caractere correto.

Pelo pouco que eu sei se `C` e de binário, eu pre suponho que tem a ver com o fato deste caracteres serem formador por duas careia de 8bits, contudo eles estão presentes na tabela `ASCII` e pelo que conheço `regex` segue a tabela `ASCII`.

Qual o motivo disto ter ocorrido?

Comment: Caracteres acentuados não pertencem ao conjunto de caracteres ASCII. Alguns conjuntos (e tem mais de um) **ASCII estendidos** - não muito mais usados hoje em dia, em favor do Unicode - de fato representam caracteres acentuados em um único byte, mas isso não é seguido que eu saiba pelo PHP ou por qualquer outra biblioteca de regex que eu conheça.

Comment: De fato, eu fiz a substituição do "." pelo respectivo caractere em Hexa "`\x82`", "`\x88`" e ele também não me retornou, contudo o operador "." significa qualquer coisa, exceto `\n`, se não configurado com `x`.

Comment: Sim. Mas eu suspeito (não sou experiente com PHP) que ele está considerando somente o primeiro byte da representação em UTF-8 de cada letra acentuada, pelo menos essa interpretação é consistente com o resultado que você está tendo. Veja minha resposta abaixo pra mais detalhes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As expressões regulares do PHP não dão suporte a Unicode por padrão, a menos que você utilize a flag `u`:

```
preg_match('~aten..o~', $string, $match);
print_r($match);
```

> Array
>   (
>   )

```
preg_match('/aten..o/u', $string, $match);
print_r($match);
```

> Array
>   (
>       [0] => atenção
>   )

[Exemplo no ideone](https://ideone.com/0MsPqG).

Quanto aos resultados que você está obtendo (ex.: `at�`), a razão disso é que os caracteres acentuados são normalmente representados por mais de um byte, por exemplo na codificação UTF-8. Um padrão:

```
at.
```

sem a flag `u` vai casar 3 bytes, o primeiro um `a`, o segundo um `t` e o terceiro o primeiro byte de `é`. Como esse primeiro byte não é um caractere ASCII (nem Unicode) válido, a função `print_r` não sabe como representá-lo, então imprime um `�`. Já o padrão:

```
aten..o
```

Quando aplicada à palavra `atenção` casa o primeiro `.` com o primeiro byte do `ç`, o segundo ponto com o segundo byte do `ç`, e quando tenta casar o `o` com o primeiro byte do `ã` não consegue, e o casamento falha.

Ativando-se a flag `u`, a engine leva em consideração caracteres completos (e não somente bytes) no casamento, de modo que o primeiro ponto casa com `ç`, o segundo com `ã`, e o resultado fica correto como esperado.

Comment: Muito boa resposta, de fato ao testar com `~aten....o~` ele me capturou a palavra correta. Não conhecia esta peculiaridade do `u`, e sempre achei que PHP seguia exatamente a `ASCII`.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Talvez você esteja confundindo ASCII com Unicode. Sugiro [esse artigo do Joel Spolsky](http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todo_Desenvolvedor_De_Software_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_Precisa_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_E_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_%28Sem_Desculpas!%29), muito bom, só não se assuste com o título hehe!

Comment: Farei esto, obrigado pelo artigo.

Answer (score 4):

Como já citado pelo @mgibsonbr, por padrão, o PHP não dá suporte ao `unicode` em expressões regulares da `preg`.

Além da solução já apresenta, o que pode ser feito é utilizar **funções de expressão regulares** do `Multibyte String`.

Exemplo:

```
$str = 'inválido';

var_dump(mb_ereg_match('inv.lido', $str)); // bool(TRUE);
```

**Observação**:

De acordo com [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4165806/3096922) no SOEN, as funções `mb_ereg_*` não estão marcadas como obsoletas. Portanto, não há problema em utilizá-las.

Comment: Funções ereg foram descontinuadas desde o PHP 5.3 http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ereg.php

Comment: Ops, `ereg` é diferente de `mb_ereg`. Veja que nenhum `E_DEPRACATED` é disparado. Acho que você se  equivocou

Comment: Veja que a [função mb_ereg](http://php.net/mb_ereg) não está marcada como depreciada

Comment: Eu tbm não entendo pq depreciaram `ereg_*` e não  `mb_ereg_*`  junto, lol fica bem contraditorio, sem contar que `preg_*` deveria ser ou deve ser a lib padrão isso. Imagina amanha se depreciam todos funções que tenham `i` .... padrão padrão padrão! +1.

Comment: Adicionei a observação, com a resposta no SOEN, que não é depreciada funções de `ereg` da `Multi Byte`