# Preg_replace para Preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Estou com dificuldade de migrar um *script* meu que limpa caracteres de uma frase.

O `preg_replace` (depreciado) eu uso o valor e a chave do *array* para a troca, contudo o `preg_replace_callback` converte o que encontra no Regex em outro *array* independente, impedido que eu utilize a chave do anterior.

```
function LimpaTexto($texto) {

    $texto = html_entity_decode($texto);

    $texto = strtolower(trim($texto));

    $replaces = array(
        '/[áaãâäÁAAÂÄ]/'     => 'a',
        '/[éèêë&ÉEeË]/'     => 'e',
        '/[íìîïÍ]/'      => 'i',
        '/[óòõôöOÔÓÖO]/'     => 'o',
        '/[úùûüÚUUÜ]/'      => 'u',
        '/[çÇ]/'         => 'c',
        '/[ñnN]/'         => 'n',
        '/\s[\s]+/'      => '-',
        '/( )/'          => '-',
        '/( )\/( )/'          => '-',
        '/( )[-]( )/'          => '-',
        '/\//'       => '-',
        '/[^a-z0-9\-_]/' => '', 
        '/-+/'           => '-', 
        '/[.]/'          => '-'
        );

    $texto = preg_replace(array_keys($replaces), array_values($replaces), $texto);

    return $texto;
}
```

Como vê o `array_keys` é encontrado e troca pelo `array_values`.

Não consegui uma formula para usar no `preg_replace_callback`. Só se eu desmembrar caractere por caractere dentro da função *callback* e compará-los para troco, o que torna o *script* mais custoso em performance e em tamanho.

Comment: [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) não foi depreciada, o que foi [depreciado foi o modificador](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) `e`vil ;)

Comment: Pois eh... estudando melhor descobri isso. Obrigado.

Comment: Sobre o [seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89607/preg-replace-para-preg-replace-callback/411192#comment181753_89621) de não entender bem inglês: existe documentação em português também -> https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 1):

A função [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) não está *deprecated*. O que foi removido no PHP 7 é a [*flag* `e`](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), mas como você não usa ela em nenhuma das regex, não há problema.

Apenas para complementar, é possível remover os acentos de outra maneira. Primeiro você deve ter instalada a extensão [PHP-Normalizer-extension (intl)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php). Aí basta [normalizar](https://www.php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php) a string e aplicar a regex `/\p{M}/u`:

```
$replaces = array(
    '/\p{M}/u'       => '',
    '/N/'            => 'n',
    '/\s[\s]+/'      => '-',
    '/( )/'          => '-',
    '/( )\/( )/'     => '-',
    '/( )[-]( )/'    => '-',
    '/\//'           => '-',
    '/[^a-z0-9\-_]/' => '', 
    '/-+/'           => '-', 
    '/[.]/'          => '-'
    );
$texto = preg_replace(array_keys($replaces), array_values($replaces), Normalizer::normalize($texto, Normalizer::FORM_D));
```

Basicamente, a normalização para NFD (o `FORM_D` acima) decompõe um caractere acentuado em dois ou mais. Por exemplo, o `á` é decomposto em dois caracteres: a letra `a` sem acento, e o próprio acento `´`. Em seguida, a regex `\p{M}` busca pelos caracteres que possuem as categorias Unicode ["Mark, Spacing Combining"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mc/index.htm), ["Mark, Enclosing"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Me/index.htm) ou ["Mark, Nonspacing"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mn/index.htm), que englobam todos esses acentos.

E vale lembrar que esse código não se limita aos acentos. Por exemplo, o caractere `ç` (cê-cedilha) em NFD é decomposto em dois: a letra `c` e o caractere **̧** ([COMBINING CEDILLA](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/327/index.htm)), e como o COMBINING CEDILLA está na categoria "Mark, Nonspacing", ele também é removido, por isso o `ç` acaba sendo substituído por `c`.

De qualquer forma, a regex `\p{M}`, juntamente com a normalização, já remove todos os acentos (obs: o algoritmo de normalização é [definido pelo Unicode](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/), e para mais detalhes sobre o seu funcionamento, leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/406545/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/345946/112052)).

---

As outras expressões são as mesmas do seu código, embora eu ache que haja espaços para melhorias, já que o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s` significa ["espaço, TAB, quebras de linha, entre outros"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405703/112052), então ter uma regex com `\s` e em seguida outra com somente espaço, e ambas substituindo pelo mesmo caractere, me parece redundante.

Outro detalhe é que `[\s]+` é o mesmo que `\s+` (quando só há um elemento dentro de uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), ou seja, dentro dos colchetes, não há ganho nenhum em usá-los, então eles podem ser removidos). Então a segunda regex ficaria `\s\s+` (duas ou mais ocorrências de `\s`), que você pode simplificar para `\s{2,}`.

As expressões `/( )\/( )/` e `/( )[-]( )/` podem ser trocadas por `/( )[-\/]( )/` (espaço, seguido de hífen ou barra, e outro espaço). Na verdade você pode até tirar esses parênteses e deixar somente os espaços, que não fará diferença. Os parênteses formam [grupos de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), mas como você não usa os grupos para nada, não precisa deles. Entendo que em alguns casos, os parênteses servem para deixar claro que há um espaço ali (alguns acham que fica mais legível do que `/ \/ /`, ou mais "óbvio" que tem espaços na expressão), mas eles não são necessários para que essa regex funcione.

Repare também que troquei `[ñnN]` por apenas `N`, já que você estava substituindo esses caracteres por `n`. Mas como a primeira regex já remove os acentos (então `ñ` se torna `n`) e trocar `n` por `n` é redundante, sobraria apenas `[N]` - mas como já foi dito, quando há apenas um elemento entre os colchetes, estes podem ser removidos, então esta expressão ficaria apenas `N`.

---

Outro detalhe é que `'/[^a-z0-9\-_] /'=> ''` vai remover tudo que **não** for letras minúsculas, números, hífen ou `_`. Isso quer dizer que essa regex também remove o ponto final da string, e quando chegar na última expressão (`[.]`), não haverá mais pontos na string para serem substituídos por `-` (pois `preg_replace` [aplica as substituições na ordem em que aparecem no array](https://ideone.com/HftCHk)). Veja se é isso mesmo que você pretende (se for, então a regex `[.]` não servirá para nada, pois o ponto já foi removido anteriormente e não haverá nada para ela substituir).

Aliás, mais um detalhe: se quer uma regex que pegue somente o ponto final, pode trocar para `/\./` Esse é um detalhe meio confuso, mas basicamente, fora dos colchetes, os [meta-caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) (aqueles que possuem significado especial, como o `.`, que significa "[qualquer caractere (exceto quebras de linha)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)") precisam ser escapados com `\`, e dentro dos colchetes, [geralmente não](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#special).

Por fim, as duas últimas expressões (`-+`, que é "um ou mais hífens", e `[.]`, que é o próprio caractere ponto), podem ser trocadas por `/-+|\./` (o caractere `|` indica uma [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), ou seja, a regex corresponde a `-+` **ou** `\.`). Você pode fazer assim porque ambas estão sendo substituídas pela mesma coisa, então não tem porque fazê-lo separadamente em duas regex.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente recomendo a leitura [desta questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81600/regex-operador-captura-de-meta-caracter), pois pelas respostas e pelo artigo relacionado veras que as `REGEX` em `PHP` não tem suporte aos caracteres Unicode, assim como dito pelo @mgibsonbr.

Desta forma as expressões

```
'/[áaãâäÁAAÂÄ]/'
'/[éèêë&ÉEeË]/'
'/[íìîïÍ]/'
'/[óòõôöOÔÓÖO]/'
'/[úùûüÚUUÜ]/'
'/[çÇ]/'
'/[ñnN]/'
```

não iram funcionar.

Para revolver este problema pode se usar a função `str_replace`, que ira busca exatamente pelo carácter especificado.

Por exemplo esta função:

```
function changeLetters($string, $down = true){

    $letters = array(
        'A'=>array('@','â','ä','à','å','Ä','Å','á','ª','Á','Â','À','ã','Ã'),
        'E'=>array('&','é','ê','ë','è','É','£','Ê','Ë','È'),
        'I'=>array('!','ï','î','ì','¡','Í','Î','Ï','Ì','í'),
        'O'=>array('ô','ö','ò','Ö','ø','Ø','ó','º','¤','ð','Ó','Ô','Ò','õ','Õ'),
        'U'=>array('ü','û','ù','Ü','ú','µ','Ú','Û','Ù'),
        'B'=>array('ß'),
        'C'=>array('Ç','ç','©','¢'),
        'D'=>array('Ð'),
        'F'=>array('ƒ'),
        'L'=>array('¦'),
        'N'=>array('ñ','Ñ'),
        'S'=>array('$','§'),
        'X'=>array('×'),
        'Y'=>array('ÿ','¥','ý','Ý'),
        'AE'=>array('æ','Æ'),
        'P'=>array('þ','Þ'),
        'R'=>array('®'),
        '0'=>array('°'),
        '1'=>array('¹','ı'),
        '2'=>array('²'),
        '3'=>array('³'),
    );

    foreach ($letters as $letter => $change){
        if($down){ $letter = down($letter); }
        $string = str_replace($change, $letter, $string);
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Comment: Olá meu amigo. Obrigado pela resposta.
Estudando um pouco mais concluí que minha função pode continuar sendo usada porque não está depreciada. Meu inglês é muito ruim então não compreendi direito o texto no Manual do PHP. 

Mas a questão que você levantou, na separação dos caracteres é bem interessante, contudo a função que descrevo na pergunta funciona perfeitamente já a 5 anos, sem nenhum bug. 

Minha preocupação era a migração para uma nova função, não existindo me alivia bastante.