# Como inverter uma String?

Tags: java, string

Um usuário digitará uma frase e devo mostrar esta frase invertida e em maiúsculo. Como posso fazer isto?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class ExerLar01 {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            char vetor[];
            String frase = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite uma frase: ");
            vetor = frase.toCharArray();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Tente usar o método [`reverse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse--) do [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase//docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

```
String hi = "Hello world";
System.out.println(new StringBuilder(hi).reverse().toString());
```

Veja este exemplo funcionando aqui no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/OttF79)**.

Adaptando para seu caso:

```
 String frase = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite uma frase: ");
 String fraseInvertida = new StringBuilder(frase).reverse().toString();
    System.out.println(fraseInvertida);
//ou
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fraseInvertida);
```

> Isso só funciona se a versão do JDK for 1.5 ou superior. Para versões
>   mais antigas, basta alterar `StringBuilder` por `StringBuffer`.

Referencia: [**Reverse a string in Java**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7569370/5524514).

Comment: Deu certo obrigada, nossa tão simples eu estava complicando muito vlw

Comment: StringBuilder é uma classe?

Comment: @Sarah sim, é uma classe para manipular Strings, assim como a StringBuffer também.

Comment: Obrigada, deu certo

Comment: @Sarah Não sei como o `JOptionPane` lida com caracteres acentuados ou emojis, mas de qualquer forma coloquei [uma resposta abaixo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/345946/112052) complementando o assunto

Comment: @hkotsubo isso foge completamente ao que foi perguntado.

Comment: @ArticunoL Acho que não, a pergunta é "como inverter uma String", e uma String pode ter acentos, emojis, etc. A menos que o JOptionPane não suporte esses caracteres.

Comment: @hkotsubo exato, a pergunta nao citou nada disso q você falou, tanto que resposta foi aceita. Se houvesse necessidade de tratar acentos ou emojis, que jamais fora mencionado pelo autor, a resposta com certeza teria sido editada ou a autora mencionado.

Comment: @ArticunoL Entendo o seu ponto de vista, mas de qq forma, se vc busca no google "como inverter string java", esta pergunta é um dos primeiros resultados, e por isso quis deixar uma solução mais "geral" para futuros visitantes. Por favor, não me entenda mal, eu não quis dizer que sua resposta está errada (inclusive votei nela), só quis deixar registrado que, dependendo do caso, o StringBuilder pode não resolver.

Comment: @hkotsubo eu entendo, não há problema algum na sua resposta, que inclusive ficou ótima, por sinal. Só comentei porque você fez questão de citar a autora aqui nos comentários, o que pode levar a uma interpretação errônea dela de que a minha resposta está errada. Só quis deixar claro que em nenhum momento foi mencionado a situação que você abordou, e o foco do site é objetividade, se a gente for parar pra abordar todas a situações possiveis, as respostas vão ficar cansativas e sem margem para que outros, como você mesmo fez aqui, responderem com complementos.

Comment: @ArticunoL É, agora percebo que posso ter passado a impressão errada para a autora. Mil desculpas pelo mal-entendido, não foi essa minha intenção

Answer (score 19):

Apenas complementando, a [solução proposta com `StringBuilder`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/116064/112052) funciona muito bem, mas há casos que não são cobertos, se levarmos em conta todas as possibilidades do [Unicode](http://unicode.org/).

Um exemplo é quando os caracteres são acentuados. Por exemplo, `í` (a letra `i` com acento agudo), segundo o Unicode, pode ser representada de duas maneiras:

1. como o [code point U+00ED (LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH ACUTE)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ed/index.htm) (`í`)
2. como uma combinação de dois code points:

   - a letra `i` (sem acento): [U+0069 (LATIN SMALL LETTER I)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0069/index.htm)
   - o acento agudo: [U+0301 (COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0301/index.htm)

*Code points são valores numéricos que o Unicode define para cada caractere. Para entender melhor, recomendo [este artigo](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) (em inglês) e [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052) (em português)*.

A primeira opção é chamada *Normalization Form C* (NFC) e a segunda, *Normalization Form D* (NFD) - ambas descritas [aqui](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/), e também há uma explicação [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/406545/112052). Na forma NFD, o caractere que corresponde ao acento agudo (COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT) é aplicado ao caractere anterior (no caso, a letra `i` - LATIN SMALL LETTER I), e quando você imprime a `String`, ambos "se juntam", formando o `í`.

É possível ter `Strings` nas duas formas, e ao imprimí-las, ambas serão mostradas como `í`. Mas internamente, os code points serão diferentes. O mesmo vale para os demais caracteres acentuados, como `ô`, `ã` e até mesmo caracteres que não são necessariamente acentuados, como o `ç`, que na forma NFD resulta na letra `c` seguida do [caractere cedilha (COMBINING CEDILLA)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/327/index.htm).

Saber disso é importante porque o método [`StringBuilder::reverse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse--) inverte a ordem dos code points, o que significa que o resultado pode não ser o esperado, dependendo da forma que a `String` está. Para mostrar o que acontece quando a `String` está em NFD, vou usar a classe [`java.text.Normalizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html), para criar uma `String` normalizada em NFD, e em seguida usarei o `StringBuilder` para invertê-la:

```
// normalizar em NFD
String s = Normalizer.normalize("ímãs", Normalizer.Form.NFD);
System.out.println(s); // ímãs
s = new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString();
System.out.println(s); // s̃aḿi
```

O método `Normalizer::normalize` retorna a `String` normalizada em NFD. Isso quer dizer que `í` está internamente guardado como dois code points: a letra `i` e o acento agudo. O mesmo vale para o `ã`, que na forma NFD corresponde a dois code points: a letra `a` e o til.

Repare que ao imprimir, esses code points são mostrados como se fossem uma coisa só (os caracteres `í`, `ã`). Mas ao inverter a `String`, o til ficou em cima do `s` e o acento ficou em cima do `m`. Isso acontece porque o `StringBuilder` inverteu todos os code points. Em outras palavras:

- Code points da `String` original (`ímãs`) normalizada em NFD:

  - letra `i` [(LATIN SMALL LETTER I)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/69/index.htm)
  - acento agudo [(COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/301/index.htm)
  - letra `m` [(LATIN SMALL LETTER M)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/6d/index.htm)
  - letra `a` [(LATIN SMALL LETTER A)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/61/index.htm)
  - til [(COMBINING TILDE)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/303/index.htm)
  - letra `s` [(LATIN SMALL LETTER S)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/73/index.htm)
- `StringBuilder::reverse` inverte os codepoints:

  - letra `s` [(LATIN SMALL LETTER S)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/73/index.htm)
  - til [(COMBINING TILDE)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/303/index.htm)
  - letra `a` [(LATIN SMALL LETTER A)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/61/index.htm)
  - letra `m` [(LATIN SMALL LETTER M)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/6d/index.htm)
  - acento agudo [(COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/301/index.htm)
  - letra `i` [(LATIN SMALL LETTER I)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/69/index.htm)

Após a inversão feita por `StringBuilder::reverse`, o acento agudo ficou depois da letra `m`, por isso ele é aplicado nesta letra, e o `i` fica sem acento. O mesmo vale para o til, que após a inversão, ficou depois do `s` e por isso é aplicado nesta letra (e não no `a`). Se o seu console não mostrar corretamente a saída, segue uma imagem de como ficou aqui:

[image: string invertida com acentos errados]

O `StringBuilder` só funcionará se a `String` estiver normalizada em NFC, pois nesse caso os caracteres acentuados serão o [`í` (LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH ACUTE)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ed/index.htm) e o [`ã` (LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH TILDE)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e3/index.htm). Como eles são representados por apenas um único code point, o acento destes caracteres não "muda de lugar" após a chamada de `StringBuilder::reverse`.

O problema é que você pode receber a `String` em qualquer uma das formas, mas se você imprimí-la, sempre será mostrada como `ímãs`. No exemplo acima eu forcei a `String` para estar em NFD e por isso você pode achar que isso não vai acontecer em "condições normais", mas pode acontecer de um usuário copiar (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) um texto de algum lugar e colar (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) na sua aplicação, e se o texto original estiver em NFD, os acentos da `String` invertida ficarão trocados. Não há como controlar isso (o texto original pode estar em qualquer outro programa que o usuário estiver usando, e o usuário sequer sabe se está em NFD ou NFC, porque na tela sempre é mostrado o acento corretamente) - veja um exemplo [neste link](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode#accounting-for-lookalikes) (copie e cole as palavras `mañana` (NFC) e `mañana` (NFD), e veja a diferença).

Então uma solução seria usar o método [`Normalizer::isNormalized`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html#isNormalized-java.lang.CharSequence-java.text.Normalizer.Form-) para verificar se a `String` está normalizada em NFC, e caso não esteja, normalizá-la antes de invertê-la:

```
// inverte a String mantendo os acentos
if (! Normalizer.isNormalized(s, Normalizer.Form.NFC)) { // se não está em NFC, normaliza
    s = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFC);
}
s = new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString(); // sãmí
```

Com isso, os acentos são preservados nos caracteres corretos e o resultado é `sãmí` (se quiser, pode chamar `normalize` direto, pois caso a string já esteja em NFC, ela não será alterada). Mas isso ainda não resolve **todos** os casos.

---

### Emojis

Emojis adicionam uma nova camada de complexidade nessa história. E como o seu uso é cada vez mais comum, é importante saber trabalhar com eles.

Geralmente os emojis correspondem a um code point, mas nem sempre é o caso. Os [emojis de famílias](https://emojipedia.org/families/), por exemplo, são combinações de outros emojis. Por exemplo, uma família com [pai, mãe e 2 filhas](https://emojipedia.org/family-man-woman-girl-girl/) é na verdade uma combinação do emoji de um [homem](https://emojipedia.org/man/), uma [mulher](https://emojipedia.org/woman/) e dois emojis de [menina](https://emojipedia.org/girl/). Para juntá-los, é usado o caractere [*ZERO WIDTH JOINER*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200d/index.htm) (também chamado apenas de **ZWJ** - e essas sequências de emojis separados por ZWJ são chamados de [*Emoji ZWJ Sequences*](https://emojipedia.org/emoji-zwj-sequences/)).

Ou seja, o emoji de "família com pai, mãe e 2 filhas" é na verdade uma sequência de **sete** code points:

- [MAN](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f468/index.htm)
- [ZERO WIDTH JOINER](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200d/index.htm)
- [WOMAN](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f469/index.htm)
- [ZERO WIDTH JOINER](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200d/index.htm)
- [GIRL](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f467/index.htm)
- [ZERO WIDTH JOINER](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200d/index.htm)
- [GIRL](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f467/index.htm)

Esta sequência de codepoints *pode* ser mostrada de diferentes maneiras. Se o sistema/programa usado reconhece esta sequência, é mostrada uma única imagem da família:

[image: emoji família com pai, mãe e 2 filhas]

Mas se esta sequência não é suportada, os emojis são mostrados um ao lado do outro:

[image: emoji família, com membros um do lado do outro, para sistemas que não suportam o emoji de família como uma única imagem]

Independente de como são mostrados, por ser uma sequência que pode corresponder a um único símbolo, não podemos trocar a ordem dos code points, pois aí ele deixa de ser interpretado como a *Emoji ZWJ Sequence* de "família com pai, mãe e 2 filhas". E se usarmos `StringBuilder::reverse` (mesmo se normalizarmos para NFC, conforme sugerido acima), a ordem destes code points será trocada para "GIRL, ZWJ, GIRL, ZWJ, WOMAN, ZWJ, MAN" e não teremos mais o "emoji de família".

---

Existem ainda outras sequências que não são separadas por ZWJ, como os emojis de bandeiras dos países. Em vez de criar um code point para cada bandeira de cada país existente no mundo, foram criados símbolos indicadores de região (*Regional Indicator Symbols*), que são caracteres que correspondem às letras de A a Z (não são as letras propriamente ditas, são caracteres **correspondentes** a estas letras, mas que ficam em [outro bloco do Unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/enclosed_alphanumeric_supplement/list.htm)).

Os códigos seguem a definição da [ISO 3166](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1#Current_codes), na qual cada país possui um código com 2 letras. A Austrália, por exemplo, tem o código "AU", então para fazer o emoji da bandeira da Austrália, basta pegar os caracteres correspondentes às letras "A" e "U" nos Regional Indicator Symbols, que no caso são:

- [Regional Indicator Symbol letter A](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f1e6/index.htm)
- [Regional Indicator Symbol letter U](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f1fa/index.htm)

Com isso, os sistemas/programas podem mostrar estes 2 code points como a bandeira da Austrália:

[image: bandeira da Austrália]

Ou, caso esta não seja suportada, mostra-se uma representação dos próprios caracteres:

[image: Regional Indicator Symbols A e U]

*Se o seu console não suporta nem a representação destes caracteres, pode ser que ele só mostre `?` ou quadrados em branco.*

Independente de como é mostrado, os dois Regional Indicator Symbols correspondem a um único "caractere" (a um único "desenho na tela"), e deveriam ser tratados como se fossem uma coisa só.
Porém, se usarmos `StringBuilder::reverse`, os code points são invertidos e o resultado são os Regional Indicator Symbols correspondentes a "UA". E como "UA" é o código da Ucrânia, o emoji resultante é a bandeira da Ucrânia:

```
// Bandeira da Austrália
int[] cp = { 0x1f1e6, 0x1f1fa };
String australia = new String(cp, 0, cp.length);
System.out.println(australia); // Bandeira da Austrália
String s = new StringBuilder( // normalização não muda nada neste caso
                Normalizer.normalize(australia, Normalizer.Form.NFC))
            // inverte os codepoints, passando a ser "UA" em vez de "AU"
            .reverse().toString();
System.out.println(s); // Bandeira da Ucrânia
```

Caso seu console não seja compatível com emojis, segue uma imagem de como seria a saída deste código:

[image: bandeiras da Austrália e Ucrânia]

Ou, no caso dos emojis de bandeiras não serem suportados, pode ser que a saída seja:

[image: Regional Indicator Symbols AU e UA]

Para que isso não aconteça, os dois Regional Indicator Symbols ("A" e "U") deveriam ser tratados como se fossem uma coisa só, mas com `StringBuilder` isso não é possível.

*Tecnicamente, a sequência de dois Regional Indicator Symbols representa o país/região (não necessariamente a bandeira em si), mas muitos sistemas costumam mostrar as respectivas bandeiras quando estes caracteres são impressos.*

---

Enfim, além dos casos já citados, há muitos outros previstos no Unicode, nos quais dois ou mais code points são interpretados como um único "caractere". O nome dado para estas sequências é [*Grapheme Cluster*](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/).

Como `StringBuilder::reverse` simplesmente inverte os code points, sem considerar se eles são parte de um *Grapheme Cluster*, a solução para inverter corretamente uma `String` é mais complicada do que simplesmente chamar este método.

Uma opção de solução é ler o [documento do Unicode que descreve os *Grapheme Clusters*](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/) e implementá-lo. *Deixo isso como exercício para o leitor*

Outra opção é ver se alguém mais inteligente já fez isso. Um exemplo é [este projeto no GitHub](https://github.com/bhamiltoncx/unicode-graphemes), que achei bem interessante, pois reconhece *Emoji ZWJ Sequences* e emojis de bandeiras como um único *Grapheme Cluster*. Com isso é possível capturar esses clusters e inverter a `String` corretamente.

Um exemplo de código com esta API:

```
import com.github.bhamiltoncx.UnicodeGraphemeParsing;
import com.github.bhamiltoncx.UnicodeGraphemeParsing.Result;

// criar uma String com vários Grapheme Clusters
int[] cp = {
        // emoji de família
        0x1f468, 0x200d, 0x1f469, 0x200d, 0x1f467, 0x200d, 0x1f467,
        // bandeira da Austrália
        0x1f1e6, 0x1f1fa,
        // outros emojis
        0x1f4a9, 0x1f4b0 };
String s = new String(cp, 0, cp.length)
        // juntar com caracteres acentuados na forma NFD
        + Normalizer.normalize("áñabc", Normalizer.Form.NFD);
System.out.println(s); // Mostrar a String original (antes de inverter)

// obter os Grapheme Clusters
List<Result> graphemeClusters = UnicodeGraphemeParsing.parse(s);
Collections.reverse(graphemeClusters); // inverter a lista de Grapheme Clusters

// construir a String invertida
StringBuilder reverse = new StringBuilder();
for (UnicodeGraphemeParsing.Result grapheme : graphemeClusters) {
    // obter o trecho da String que corresponde ao Grapheme Cluster
    String str = s.substring(grapheme.stringOffset, grapheme.stringOffset + grapheme.stringLength);
    reverse.append(str);
}
String invertida = reverse.toString();
System.out.println(invertida);
```

O método `UnicodeGraphemeParsing::parse` obtém a lista de grapheme clusters de uma `String`. Em seguida, eu uso `Collections.reverse` para inverter esta lista, e percorro-a, guardando os respectivos trechos da `String` em um `StringBuilder`, para no final ter a `String` invertida. A saída do código é:

[image: Emojis e acentos corretamente invertidos]

*Lembrando que, caso seu console não tenha suporte a ZWJ Sequences ou bandeiras, a família pode ser mostrada como 4 emojis (homem, mulher, 2 meninas) e a bandeira pode ser mostrada como os próprios Regional Indicator Symbols, conforme já mencionado anteriormente. Mas o importante é que estas sequências são tratadas como se fossem uma coisa só, não ocorrendo os problemas já citados (trocar a bandeira e desfazer a ZWJ Sequence).*

Para efeito de comparação, veja o resultado com `StringBuilder::reverse`, normalizando para NFC e NFD:

```
System.out.println("NFC:" + new StringBuilder(Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFC)).reverse().toString());
System.out.println("NFD:" + new StringBuilder(Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD)).reverse().toString());
```

A saída é:

[image: Saída com StringBuilder, emojis errados]

Repare que a conversão para NFC só corrige os acentos, mas nenhuma das formas previne o problema de inverter os code points da bandeira e da ZWJ Sequence.

---

### Regex

Caso não queira usar uma biblioteca externa, **a partir do Java 9** é possível usar `\X` para verificar um [Unicode extended grapheme cluster](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#grapheme) - que é explicado em detalhes [aqui](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Default_Grapheme_Clusters).

Porém, nos testes que fiz, ele não reconhece uma *Emoji ZWJ Sequence*, pois usando `\X`, cada emoji da sequência é considerado um *Grapheme Cluster* separado. Os emojis de bandeiras, porém, são reconhecidos corretamente. Usando como exemplo a mesma `String` do exemplo anterior:

```
int[] cp = {
        // emoji de família
        0x1f468, 0x200d, 0x1f469, 0x200d, 0x1f467, 0x200d, 0x1f467,
        // bandeira da Austrália
        0x1f1e6, 0x1f1fa,
        // outros emojis
        0x1f4a9, 0x1f4b0 };
String s = new String(cp, 0, cp.length)
        // juntar com caracteres acentuados na forma NFD
        + Normalizer.normalize("áñabc", Normalizer.Form.NFD);
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\X");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Neste exemplo estou procurando todos os *Grapheme Clusters* com `\X` (lembrando que dentro de `Strings` a barra invertida é escrita como `\\`). O resultado, porém, mostra cada emoji da *ZWJ Sequence* separadamente (a bandeira, porém, está correta):

[image: regex X mostra ZWJ sequence quebrada em vários emojis]

No [Java 13](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/13/) melhorou um pouco, mas ainda não está perfeito: o `\X` reconhece os emojis de homem e mulher como um *Grapheme Cluster*, e os dois emojis de menina como outro (em vez de considerar tudo uma coisa só).

---

Uma solução seria tentar modificar a regex para pegar uma *ZWJ Sequence* **ou** um `\X`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{InMiscellaneous_Symbols_and_Pictographs}(?:\\u200d\\p{InMiscellaneous_Symbols_and_Pictographs})*|\\X");
```

`\p{InMiscellaneous_Symbols_and_Pictographs}` serve para pegar qualquer code point que esteja no [bloco *Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs*](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/miscellaneous_symbols_and_pictographs/list.htm) (clique no link e veja que a lista é grande). Em seguida eu vejo se depois há uma ou mais ocorrências de ZWJ (`\u200d`) seguido de outro símbolo do bloco *Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs*. Usando esta regex, o *Grapheme Cluster* de família é reconhecido como se fosse um único "caractere".

Depois bastaria guardar os resultados de `m.group()` em uma lista, invertê-la e construir a `String` invertida:

```
List<String> grafemas = new ArrayList<>();
while(m.find()) {
    grafemas.add(m.group());
}
Collections.reverse(grafemas);
String invertida = String.join("", grafemas);
```

Com isso, a `String` invertida fica igual à do exemplo anterior com `UnicodeGraphemeParsing::parse`. Mas há um porém.

O bloco *Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs* não contém todos os emojis. Há vários que estão em outros blocos, como o [coração](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2764/index.htm), que está no bloco [*Dingbats*](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/dingbats/list.htm), e muitos outros espalhados por outros blocos, como o [Bloco *Emoticons*](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/emoticons/list.htm), que contém os *smiles* e outros símbolos (além disso, há blocos podem ter outros caracteres que não são emojis). Enfim, tentar fazer uma regex que contemple todos os emojis possíveis [não é tão simples assim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24840667). Outra opção é se limitar somente às [ZWJ Sequences descritas no Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/11.0/emoji-zwj-sequences.txt), fazendo uma regex que contemple somente aquelas sequências (mesmo assim é um trabalho considerável).

---

#### Java <= 8

No Java 8 não há suporte ao `\X`, mas encontrei uma alternativa [nesta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4307261). Infelizmente, não é nada simples:

```
String extendedGraphemeCluster = "(?:(?:\\u000D\\u000A)|(?:[\\u0E40\\u0E41\\u0E42\\u0E43\\u0E44\\u0EC0\\u0EC1\\u0EC2\\u0EC3\\u0EC4\\uAAB5\\uAAB6\\uAAB9\\uAABB\\uAABC]*(?:[\\u1100-\\u115F\\uA960-\\uA97C]+|([\\u1100-\\u115F\\uA960-\\uA97C]*((?:[[\\u1160-\\u11A2\\uD7B0-\\uD7C6][\\uAC00\\uAC1C\\uAC38]][\\u1160-\\u11A2\\uD7B0-\\uD7C6]*|[\\uAC01\\uAC02\\uAC03\\uAC04])[\\u11A8-\\u11F9\\uD7CB-\\uD7FB]*))|[\\u11A8-\\u11F9\\uD7CB-\\uD7FB]+|[^[\\p{Zl}\\p{Zp}\\p{Cc}\\p{Cf}&&[^\\u000D\\u000A\\u200C\\u200D]]\\u000D\\u000A])[[\\p{Mn}\\p{Me}\\u200C\\u200D\\u0488\\u0489\\u20DD\\u20DE\\u20DF\\u20E0\\u20E2\\u20E3\\u20E4\\uA670\\uA671\\uA672\\uFF9E\\uFF9F][\\p{Mc}\\u0E30\\u0E32\\u0E33\\u0E45\\u0EB0\\u0EB2\\u0EB3]]*)|(?s:.))";
```

Fiz um teste com esta regex e infelizmente ela não reconhece os emojis de bandeira como se fosse um único *Grapheme Cluster* (cada Regional Indicator Symbol é considerado um cluster separado) - além de também quebrar a ZWJ Sequence em vários emojis, da mesma forma que `\X`. Ou seja, além de tentar entender esta regex, você ainda terá que modificá-la para contemplar estes casos. Uma tentativa:

```
String extendedGraphemeCluster = "(?:(?:\\u000D\\u000A)|(?:[\\u0E40\\u0E41\\u0E42\\u0E43\\u0E44\\u0EC0\\u0EC1\\u0EC2\\u0EC3\\u0EC4\\uAAB5\\uAAB6\\uAAB9\\uAABB\\uAABC]*(?:[\\u1100-\\u115F\\uA960-\\uA97C]+|([\\u1100-\\u115F\\uA960-\\uA97C]*((?:[[\\u1160-\\u11A2\\uD7B0-\\uD7C6][\\uAC00\\uAC1C\\uAC38]][\\u1160-\\u11A2\\uD7B0-\\uD7C6]*|[\\uAC01\\uAC02\\uAC03\\uAC04])[\\u11A8-\\u11F9\\uD7CB-\\uD7FB]*))|[\\u11A8-\\u11F9\\uD7CB-\\uD7FB]+|[^[\\p{Zl}\\p{Zp}\\p{Cc}\\p{Cf}&&[^\\u000D\\u000A\\u200C\\u200D]]\\u000D\\u000A])[[\\p{Mn}\\p{Me}\\u200C\\u200D\\u0488\\u0489\\u20DD\\u20DE\\u20DF\\u20E0\\u20E2\\u20E3\\u20E4\\uA670\\uA671\\uA672\\uFF9E\\uFF9F][\\p{Mc}\\u0E30\\u0E32\\u0E33\\u0E45\\u0EB0\\u0EB2\\u0EB3]]*)|(?s:.))";
String zwjSequence = "\\p{InMiscellaneous_Symbols_and_Pictographs}(?:\\u200d\\p{InMiscellaneous_Symbols_and_Pictographs})*";
String flag = "[\\x{1f1e6}-\\x{1f1ff}]{2}";
// regex com ZWJ Sequence, ou sequência de bandeira, ou grapheme cluster
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(zwjSequence + "|" + flag + "|" + extendedGraphemeCluster);
```

Com isso, as *ZWJ Sequences* e os emojis de bandeiras são reconhecidos como um único Grapheme Cluster (com todos os poréns já mencionados antes, sobre o bloco *Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs* não ter todos os emojis), mas infelizmente não funciona para caracteres coreanos: por exemplo, o caractere [`각`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ac01/index.htm) na forma NFD é composto por 3 codepoints: [`ᄀ` (HANGUL CHOSEONG KIYEOK)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1100/index.htm), [`ᅡ` (HANGUL JUNGSEONG A)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1161/index.htm) e [`ᆨ` (HANGUL JONGSEONG KIYEOK )](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/11a8/index.htm). Mas a regex acima não reconhece estes 3 code points como um único Grapheme Cluster. Já as soluções anteriores (`UnicodeGraphemeParsing::parse` e `\X` do Java 9) reconhecem este Grapheme Cluster corretamente.

Nesse caso, eu acho melhor partir para uma biblioteca, como [a que indiquei acima](https://github.com/bhamiltoncx/unicode-graphemes) - não testei para todos os casos possíveis, como por exemplo caracteres de idiomas diferentes (testei somente com caracteres japoneses e coreanos e funcionou), mas tudo depende dos seus casos de uso.

---

Isso não quer dizer que [a solução com `StringBuilder::reverse`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/116064/112052) está errada. Se você só está lidando com caracteres ASCII (ou com textos em português/inglês/qualquer idioma que use o alfabeto latino), basta lembrar de normalizar a `String` para NFC que não terá problemas (talvez haja um caso ou outro, vai saber, mas para a maioria dos casos que só usam ASCII deve funcionar).

Só quis mostrar que há vários outros casos que, caso surjam, exigirão uma solução mais abrangente (e complicada). E reconheço que a minha resposta não está completa (no sentido de contemplar todas as possibilidades previstas pelo Unicode), pois ainda estou começando a me aprofundar no assunto (Unicode é muito mais complicado do que pensei) e com certeza há muito mais detalhes que ainda desconheço (só sei que nada sei...)

Comment: Se puderem explicar o motivo do voto negativo, ficarei feliz em corrigir o problema...

Answer (score 6):

Quando a linguagem não disponibiliza um método para fazer isso, eu geralmente uso o seguinte algorítimo:

```
public String reverse(String str) {
  char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
  int numChars = chars.length - 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < numChars / 2; i++) {
    char temp = chars[i];
    chars[i] = chars[numChars - i];
    chars[numChars - i] = temp;
  }
  return new String(chars);
}
```

Ele funciona substituindo o primeiro char pelo último char, o segundo pelo penúltimo, o terceiro pelo antepenúltimo e assim por diante.

Não sei se é o melhor, ou se tem alguma limitação, mas sempre atendeu o que eu precisava. (As únicas vezes que precisei reverter uma String foram em exercícios.)

É mais ou menos assim que o reverse do StringBuilder funciona.

Comment: A vantagem do StringBuilder é que ele gerencia a string no "escopo de memória" dele.
Da maneira que você programou a VM vai criar várias string no pool de strings até chegar on resultado final.

Comment: Na verdade não. O código que fiz criará apenas UMA instância de String no retorno do método. Toda a operação é feita em cima de um ÚNICO array de caracteres e não em Strings.

Comment: Me desculpa Leonardo, tem razão. Não tinha visto a conversão para arrays. Falei m***

Comment: Que isso, não precisa pedir desculpa! Sua preocupação é legitima. Se fossem Strings, isso que você disse realmente aconteceria, e performance não seria nada boa ahaha.

Comment: @fernandosavio e Leonardo, apenas para complementar, um caractere (no sentido de "um único símbolo mostrado na tela") [nem sempre vai ocupar apenas um `char`](https://www.javaworld.com/article/3067393/learn-java/when-is-a-character-not-a-character.html), então inverter o array de `char` nem sempre funciona para todos os casos. Eu detalho um pouco disso na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/345946/112052)

Answer (score 4):

Java não é o meu forte mas vou deixar aqui a versão recursiva para inverter uma string:

```
class Main {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
      String str = "miguel";
      System.out.println(new Main().str_reverse(str).toUpperCase()); // LEUGIM
  }
  public String str_reverse(String str) {
      if(str.isEmpty()) {
          return str;
      }
      // concatenar ultimo caracter com o resto string excepto o ultimo
      return str.substring(str.length() - 1) + str_reverse(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1));
  }
}
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/EveryFreshDevelopers)

Answer (score -5):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {           
    Scanner entrada= new Scanner(System.in);
    String x =entrada.next();
    char charAt = x.charAt(0);
    String invertido="";

    for(int i=0;i<x.length();i++) {
        invertido= x.charAt(i)+invertido;
    }

    System.out.println(invertido);
}
```

Comment: Em um linguagem robusta, e "antiga" como o Java, é bem provável que se tenham muito métodos já prontos. É ótimo que se saiba como criar um algorítimo para fazer algo, sem usar coisas já prontas, porém é melhor no dia a dia já usar o que a linguagem oferece pra não reinventar a roda, por questões de Clean Code e manutenibilidade do código.

Comment: Para seu código funcionar corretamente teria que usar `entrada.nextLine()`, caso digite mais  que uma palavra. E você pode simplificar iterando os caracteres do último índice até o primeiro: `public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
  String x = entrada.nextLine();
  String invertido = "";
  
  for (int i = x.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   invertido += x.charAt(i);
  }

  System.out.println(invertido);
 }`