# Duvida Normalizer + Regex

Tags: java, regex

Alguem poderia me explicar o código abaixo?

```
returnStr = Normalizer.normalize(returnStr, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
    .replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
```

returnStr tem como valor inicial uma url.

Comment: O `\p` possui um ancora negada `\P`, desta forma a regex poderia ser simplesmente `"\\P{ASCII}"`, não necessitando do `[^ ]`

Comment: mas porque "\\p" e não só "\p"? não entendi essa parte do regex

Comment: Pois se trata de um string, em string o caractere de `\ ` é um atalho para literal, desta forma p resultado final da conversão da string para REGEX é `[^\p{ASCII}]`, que a torna correta, se tive-se so um `\ ` ficaria `[^p{ASCII}]` e geraria um erro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Analisando a sentença `[^\\p{ASCII}]`

- Ela esta em um *String* que sera convertida em REGEX, e o <kbd>\</kbd> em *String* é um caractere de escape, que torna próximo literal, assim apos a conversão o resultado sera `[^\p{ASCII}]`.
- `[]` significa uma cadeia que sera capturada, `[^ ]` é uma cadeia negada, ou seja em vez de capturar apenas o que se enquadra na cadeia, ele vai capturar tudo que **não** se enquadra.
- `\p`*, assim como `\w`, `\d`, `\x` é uma ancora, serve para se escrever menos, em vez de fazer `[A-Za-z0-9_]` basta um `\w`
- `{ASCII}` é uma condição para o `\p`, isso vai depender a biblioteca REGEX da linguagem/compilador que esta usando.

#### Nota

Usando o [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/#pcre), em *Quick reference*>*Meta sequences* temos o `\p`.

> Corresponde a um caractere unicode que foi passado como parametro.

[Nesta pagina](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCOS_regexp#GCOS_regexp_unitype) temos alguns controladores suportados, contudo comparando com a [tabela ASCII](http://187.7.106.14/marcelo/org_comp/tabelaASCII.pdf), nem todas as sentenças batem, isso porque a [tabela ASCII só é padrão do 0-127](http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todo_Desenvolvedor_De_Software_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_Precisa_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_E_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_%28Sem_Desculpas!%29), apos isso ela não segue um padrão absoluto então vai depender a linguagem que esta usando, por exemplo a *pcre* pelo que vi, não tem suporte ao `{ASCII}` do `\p`.

#### Adendo

O `\p` possui uma ancora negada `\P`, desta forma você poderia converte a *String* simplesmente para `\\P{ASCII}`, não necessitando da cadeia negada `[^ ]`.

Answer (score 1):

Analisando a expressão regular, trata-se de uma lista negada. Ele substituirá
qualquer ocorrência de caractere não ASCII por vazio (removerá).

1. Pegue a URL
2. Remova qualquer caractere não ASCII.

ASCII é uma tabela de caracteres, contendo letras números e símbolos e código computacional correspodente a ele.

Comment: A resposta esta certa, mas creio que ficaria melhor se explica-se o porque dele considerar caracteres ASCII, explicando que o `\p` se trata de uma "ancora/atalho" assim como `\x`, na qual creio que seja a real duvida do AP.

Answer (score 1):

As outras respostas focaram em explicar a regex, mas faltou explicar a parte do `Normalizer`, e como ambos funcionam juntos.

---

## Regex

Apenas para complementar/reafirmar, pois já foi coberto em detalhes pelas outras respostas, [o atalho `\\p{ASCII}` está definido na documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#posix) desta forma:

```
\p{ASCII}   All ASCII:[\x00-\x7F]
```

Ou seja, ele é equivalente a todos os caracteres da [tabela ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) (code points entre zero e 127, que acima estão escritos em hexadecimal: `\x00` e `\x7F`). Para entender o que é um code point, [leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052)

> Lembrando que a barra invertida é escrita como `\\` por causa das regras de escape da linguagem.

Já o `[^ ]` é uma [classe de caracteres negada](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) (qualquer coisa que **não** seja o que está dentro dos colchetes). Por isso a expressão está pegando qualquer caractere que **não** seja ASCII (e como já dito em outra resposta, a expressão `[^\\p{ASCII}]` poderia ser trocada por `\\P{ASCII}` - com "P" maiúsculo).

---

## `Normalizer`

Já o [`Normalizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/text/Normalizer.html) serve para aplicar as normalizações Unicode em uma string. Para entender em detalhes, sugiro ler [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/406545/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/345946/112052) (e para se aprofundar no assunto, pode ler todas as [perguntas relacionadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/394834?sort=hot)).

Mas de maneira **bem** resumida, o [Unicode](http://unicode.org/main.html) define que alguns caracteres possuem mais de uma forma de serem representados. Por exemplo, o `á` (letra "a" com acento agudo) pode ser representado de duas formas:

1. composta - como o code point [U+00E1 (LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e1) (á)
2. decomposta - como uma combinação de dois code points (nesta ordem):

   - a letra "a" (sem acento): [U+0061 (LATIN SMALL LETTER A)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0061)
   - o acento agudo: [U+0301 (COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0301)

A primeira forma é chamada NFC (Canonical Composition), e a segunda, NFD (Canonical Decomposition). As duas formas acima são consideradas "canonicamente equivalentes", quando se trata de representar a letra `a` com acento agudo. Ou seja, são duas formas de se representar a mesma coisa.

Portanto, `Normalizer.normalize(returnStr, Normalizer.Form.NFD)` está convertendo a string para a forma NFD. Se ela tiver caracteres acentuados, eles serão decompostos de acordo com a descrição acima: o `á` é decomposto em `a` e o [acento agudo](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0301), `õ` é decomposto em `o` e o [til](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0303/index.htm), `ç` é decomposto em `c` e a [cedilha](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0327/index.htm), etc.

E como os caracteres que representam os acentos/cedilha não estão na faixa de valores do ASCII, o `replaceAll` acaba removendo-os, sobrando apenas as letras sem acentos/cedilha.

Portanto, o que esse código faz é remover os acentos e a cedilha (`á`, `â`, `ã` e `á` se tornam `a`, `ç` se torna `c`, etc). Ex:

```java
String str = "opção";

// imprime "opcao"
System.out.println(Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", ""));
```

Vale lembrar que a regex remove qualquer caractere que não seja ASCII, o que quer dizer que letras de outros idiomas, entre outros caracteres, como emojis, também serão removidos:

```java
String str = "時opção";

// além dos acentos, também remove o caractere japonês e o emoji, e imprime "opcao"
System.out.println(Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", ""));
```

Sem contar os milhares de caracteres "especiais" que o Unicode define, como os vários tipos diferentes de [espaços](https://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html), [hífens](https://jkorpela.fi/dashes.html), [aspas](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Emgk25/ucs/quotes.html), etc, muitos deles - a maioria, na verdade - fora da tabela ASCII, e portanto seriam removidos também.

---

Mas aí é claro que depende das strings que você tem. Se só tiver textos em português, por exemplo, não seria tão problemático assim. Mas se tiver outros caracteres não-ASCII que não deveriam ser removidos, aí teria que mudar a regex de acordo com cada caso. Um exemplo seria remover apenas os acentos, usando a categoria Unicode a qual eles pertencem, por exemplo:

```java
Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{M}", "")
```

No caso, `\\p{M}` pega apenas as categorias [Mark, Spacing Combining](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mc/index.htm), [Mark, Enclosing](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Me/index.htm) e [Mark, Nonspacing](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Me/index.htm), que possuem os caracteres de acentuação e a cedilha (não só os usados no português, clique nos links para ver a lista completa). Assim, emojis e letras de outros alfabetos são preservadas. Mas enfim, aí já foge um pouco do escopo da pergunta, é só para mostrar que regex não é algo mágico e depende muito de ajustes que variam conforme o contexto (ainda mais quando envolve essas propriedades Unicode).