# Remover acentos - [\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}] vs [^\\p{ASCII}]

Tags: java, string, regex, replace

Criei um código em `Java` para remover os acentos como o seguinte:

```
private String removerAcentos(String texto) {
  texto = Normalizer.normalize(texto, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
  texto = texto.replaceAll("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]", "");

  return texto;
}
```

Gostaria de saber a diferença entre o `[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]` e `[^\\p{ASCII}]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]` = Somente caracteres Unicode
`[^\\p{ASCII}]` = Não latinos

Answer (score 5):

Ao contrário do que a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/165565/112052) dá a entender, ambas as expressões consideram "caracteres Unicode". O que muda é **quais caracteres** são considerados em cada uma.

Além disso, a descrição de lá está errada. `\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}` não é "*somente caracteres Unicode*", e sim "somente ***Combining Diacritical Marks***", que é uma faixa bem específica do Unicode.

---

Para explicar melhor da diferença: de forma *bem* resumida, alguns caracteres acentuados como o `á` podem ser representados de duas formas:

1. composta - como o code point [U+00E1 (LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e1) ("á")
2. decomposta - como uma combinação de dois code points (nesta ordem):

   - a letra "a" (sem acento): [U+0061 (LATIN SMALL LETTER A)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0061)
   - o acento agudo: [U+0301 (COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0301)

A primeira forma é chamada de NFC, e a segunda, NFD. Para entender em mais detalhes, sugiro ler [aqui](/q/406545/112052), [aqui](/a/396555/112052) e [aqui](/a/345946/112052) (e [este](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/515134/112052) também está relacionado ao assunto).

Enfim, no código da pergunta é feita a normalização para NFD (`Normalizer.normalize(texto, Normalizer.Form.NFD)`), o que quer dizer que caracteres acentuados estarão na segunda forma descrita acima. E é aí que entra o `\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}`, pois esta expressão considera somente o *COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT*, pois este caractere pertence ao [bloco "*Combining Diacritical Marks*"](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/combining_diacritical_marks/list.htm) <- veja neste link que ele possui vários acentos, incluindo os usados na língua portuguesa.

Portanto o `replace` pega somente os acentos e os troca por "nada" (a string vazia). No final sobram apenas as letras, sem os respectivos acentos.

O ponto é: esta expressão pega somente os *Combining Diacritical Marks*, ignorando quaisquer outros caracteres. Ou seja, dizer que ela é para "*somente caracteres Unicode*" está errado. Ela serve para pegar apenas um bloco específico do Unicode.

> Vale lembrar que mesmo caracteres ASCII como "a" e "b" também fazem parte do Unicode (podemos dizer que Unicode é "retro-compatível" com ASCII de certa forma), então "somente caracteres Unicode" não é uma boa descrição para o que a expressão `[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]` faz. Existem milhares de caracteres Unicode que esta expressão não considera.

Outro detalhe é que em vez de usar `[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]`, você poderia ter usado apenas `\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}`. Quando existe apenas um elemento dentro dos colchetes, eles não são necessários (apesar de ser uma expressão bem comprida, ainda é "uma coisa só" e portanto não precisa dos colchetes).

---

Já a expressão `[^\\p{ASCII}]` é diferente. Repare que agora ela começa com `[^`, o que indica uma [classe de caracteres negados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated). Ou seja, é qualquer coisa que **não** seja `\\p{ASCII}`. Só que, ao contrário do que afirma a outra resposta, isso não é para caracteres "não latinos", é somente para caracteres que não sejam ASCII (ou seja, cujos code points estejam entre 0 e 127).

Só para explicar a diferença, o Unicode define vários caracteres latinos que não são ASCII ([aqui](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/latin_supplement/list.htm), [aqui](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/latin_extended_a/list.htm) e [aqui](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/latin_extended_b/list.htm), e há também uma lista consolidada [aqui](https://codepoints.net/search?sc=Latn)).

Por exemplo, o [caractere `ß` (LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00df/index.htm) não é ASCII, mas segundo o Unicode ele é "latino" (pois está no bloco "*Latin-1 Supplement*"). Isso quer dizer que se uma string tivesse este caractere, usar `\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}` não o removeria (pois ele não é um *Combining Diacritical Mark*), mas `[^\\p{ASCII}]` o removeria, pois ele não é ASCII. Veja a diferença:

```java
String texto = Normalizer.normalize("áß", Normalizer.Form.NFD);
System.out.println(texto.replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}", "")); // aß
System.out.println(texto.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "")); // a
```

> Aliás, vale mencionar que `[^\\p{ASCII}]` pode ser trocado por `\\P{ASCII}` (o "P" maiúsculo é a negação, ou seja, neste caso é "tudo que não é ASCII").

Enfim, vale avaliar se para os seus casos faz diferença. **Se só tiver textos em português, por exemplo, tanto faz usar um ou outro**.

Mas se tiver qualquer coisa que não seja ASCII (como os caracteres já citados, além de letras de outros alfabetos (japonês, árabe, cirílico, etc), emojis, etc), aí faz diferença: com `\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}` todos eles serão mantidos, mas com `[^\\p{ASCII}]` eles também serão removidos.

---

Outra opção seria usar `replaceAll("\\P{IsLatin}", "")` para remover tudo que não é um caractere latino. Com isso o `ß` será mantido, mas ainda serão removidos os demais (emojis, letras de outros alfabetos, etc). Veja a diferença:

```
String texto = Normalizer.normalize("áß" + new String(new int[] { 0x1f4a9}, 0, 1), Normalizer.Form.NFD);
System.out.println("Texto original: " + texto);
System.out.println(texto.replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}", "")); // mantém o ß e o emoji
System.out.println(texto.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", ""));  // remove o ß e o emoji
System.out.println(texto.replaceAll("\\P{IsLatin}", ""));  // mantém o ß, remove o emoji
```

A saída do código acima é:

```
Texto original: áß
aß
a
aß
```

Mas novamente, tem que ver seu contexto. Se as strings envolvidas não têm esses caracteres que fazem diferença, tanto faz qual usar.