# Inverter caracteres de uma String

Tags: java, string

Eu tenho um código que fiz pra inverter uma String, mas não atende o que necessito. Preciso que ele converta a ordem dos caracteres de cada frase.

Por exemplo: Ele converte "Oi pessoal!" em "!laossep iO". E o que eu preciso é que ele converta em "iO !laossep".

Meu código:

```
public class ex1 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String palavra = "Abobora Vermelha";
            String resultado=""; 

            for(int x = palavra.length() -1;x>=0;x--){
                resultado = resultado + palavra.charAt(x);
            }
            System.out.println(resultado);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como inverter uma String?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116062/como-inverter-uma-string)

Comment: @Marconi Não é duplicata dessa daí. Essa outra pergunta é para inverter a frase como um todo, coisa que o OP já estava fazendo, mas o problema aqui é inverter apenas as palavras individualmente sem inverter a ordem delas dentro da frase. É um problema bem semelhante e bem relacionado, mas é diferente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro, que a variável `palavra` na verdade contém uma frase. Então, para não deixar as coisas confusas, vamos chamá-la de `entrada`.

Você pode usar `entrada.split(" ")` para dividir a entrada nas palavras constituintes e então usar o seu algoritmo para invertê-las uma a uma. Também recomendo usar um `StringBuilder` para evitar criar um monte de `String`s intermediárias que serão descartadas pelo coletor de lixo e com isso ocasionar um desempenho relativamente ruim.

Seu código fica assim:

```
public class Ex1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String entrada = "Abobora Vermelha";
        StringBuilder resultado = new StringBuilder(entrada.length());

        for (String s : entrada.split(" ")) {
            if (resultado.length() != 0) resultado.append(' ');
            for (int x = s.length() - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
                resultado.append(s.charAt(x));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(resultado);
    }
}
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/azdMig)

Comment: `Primeiro, que a variável palavra na verdade contém uma frase. Então, para não deixar as coisas confusas, vamos chamá-la de entrada` adora essas partes :)

Comment: Para inverter uma `String`, você também poderia usar `new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString()`

Comment: @hkotsubo No caso, seria `resultado.append(new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString());` - no entanto, eu quis aproveitar o código que o autor da pergunta fez.