# Indicar se um caractere é vogal ou consoante

Tags: python

Escreva a função `vogal` que recebe um único caractere como parâmetro e devolve `True` se ele for uma vogal e `False` se for uma consoante.

Note que:

- `vogal("a")` deve devolver `True`
- `vogal("b")` deve devolver `False`
- `vogal("E")` deve devolver `True`

Tentei colocar esse pequeno código mas não deu certo:

```
v= str("a"),("e"),("i"),("o"),("u")
def vogal (v):
    if v == ("a")("e")("i")("o")("u"):
        return true
    else:
        return false
```

Comment: E `vogal('á')`, com a acentuado, deve retornar o quê?

Answer (score 10):

### Problemas

Os retornos que tem não estão certos:

```
return true
...
return false
```

`True` e `False` levam a primeira letra maiuscula. Como tem dá erro de execução pois nem `true` nem `false` existem.

Esta comparação também não está certa:

```
v == ("a")("e")("i")("o")("u")
```

Aqui é como se estivesse a usar o `"a"` como função pois faz `"a"("e")`. E por isso não compara com todos os valores como estaria a imaginar. Talvez quisesse fazer isto:

```
if v == "a" or v == "e" or v == "i" or v == "o" or  v =="u":
```

Que apesar de não muito idiomático já iria funcionar.

### Solução

O mais simples é mesmo utilizar o operador `in` testando com uma string que contenha apenas as vogais. Isso torna o seu código bem simples e fácil de ler:

```
def vogal (v):
    if v in "aeiou": # aqui testa com o operador in
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Agora já lhe dá o resultado esperado:

```
print(vogal('e')) # True
print(vogal('b')) # False
```

[Veja o código a correr no Ideone](https://ideone.com/1ucnWy)

Consegue até transformar a função em uma linha, embora regra geral este já seja um estilo para programadores mais experientes:

```
def vogal (v):
    return v in "aieou"
```

Para considerar também as maiúsculas, basta você informá-las na *string*:

```
def vogal(v):
    return v in "aeiouAEIOU"
```

Ou utilizar o método `lower` para converter a entrada sempre para minúscula:

```
def vogal(v):
    return v.lower() in "aeiou"
```

Comment: Obrigado !!  ajudou muito

Answer (score 1):

Apenas complementando, e sendo um pouco pedante com relação ao título ("*Indicar se um caractere é vogal ou consoante*"): entendo que a função deve retornar `True` se receber uma vogal e `False` se receber uma consoante, mas e se ela receber uma string como `'&'`, `'2'` ou `','`? Deve retornar `False` também? Pois nesses casos, os caracteres não são vogais nem consoantes, então entendo que não deveria retornar `True` nem `False` - talvez lançar uma exceção então?

Enfim, uma opção seria fazer:

```
def vogal_ou_consoante(letra):
    letra = letra.lower()
    if letra in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'):
        return True
    elif letra in ('b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'):
        return False
    else:
        raise ValueError('Não é vogal nem consoante')

print(vogal_ou_consoante('a')) # True
print(vogal_ou_consoante('B')) # False
print(vogal_ou_consoante('2')) # ValueError
```

Outro detalhe é que usei tuplas em vez de strings no [operador `in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in). Claro que se a string for `'a'`, então fazer `letra in 'aeiou'` funciona. Mas e se tivermos isso:

```
def vogal(v):
    return v.lower() in "aeiou"

print(vogal('eio')) # True
```

Repare que se a string for `'eio'`, o retorno também é `True`, já que o operador `in`, quando aplicado a strings, verifica se uma string é substring da outra.

Tudo bem que `'eio'` só tem vogais, mas se o objetivo é verificar se uma string de qualquer tamanho contém somente vogais, então deveria validar também `'oi'` e `'uia'`, mas esses casos retornam `False`. Então se queremos que a função valide somente se a string tiver apenas um caractere (e esse caractere deve ser vogal ou consoante), então devemos usar a primeira solução acima com `('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')`.

---

#### E os acentos?

Se eu tiver a string `'á'` (letra "a" com acento agudo), ela também é uma vogal, certo? Mas a função acima só considera letras não acentuadas.

Uma solução seria adicionar as letras acentuadas nas opções, algo como `letra in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'á', 'é', 'í', ... )` (não esquecendo de colocar opções nas consoantes também, para incluir caracteres como o `'ç'` e o `'ñ'`).

Outra opção é normalizar as strings para a forma NFD. Para entender em detalhes o que é isso, sugiro que leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/406545/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/396555/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/345946/112052). Mas de forma resumida, ao normalizar para NFD, letras como o "á" são decompostas em dois caracteres: a letra "a" (sem acento) e o [próprio acento](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0301/index.htm) ("´") - o mesmo vale para consoantes como o "ç", que é decomposta em dois caracteres: a letra "c" e a [cedilha](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/327/index.htm).

Sendo assim, bastaria normalizar a string e pegar o primeiro caractere (pois a normalização em NFD garante que a letra sem acento sempre é colocada antes do acento). Para isso, usamos o [módulo `unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize):

```
from unicodedata import normalize

def vogal_ou_consoante(letra):
    if len(letra) == 0:
        raise ValueError('string vazia')

    letra = normalize('NFD', letra)[0].lower()
    if letra in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'):
        return True
    elif letra in ('b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'):
        return False
    else:
        raise ValueError('Não é vogal nem consoante')

print(vogal_ou_consoante('á')) # True
print(vogal_ou_consoante('Ç')) # False
print(vogal_ou_consoante('')) # ValueError
```

Incluí uma verificação a mais para o caso em que a string é vazia (pois aí nem adianta normalizar e pegar o primeiro caractere), e nesse caso também lança uma exceção, já que uma string vazia não é vogal nem consoante.

---

Só tem um detalhe: essa implementação é meio "ingênua", pois como ela pega sempre o primeiro caractere, então ela retorna `True` se a string começar com um caractere acentuado (ex: para a string `'ábaco'`, a função acima retorna `True`).

Para corrigir isso, podemos verificar se do segundo caractere em diante só tem acentos. Para isso usamos [`combining`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.combining), que verifica se o caractere é um *combining character* (categoria na qual os acentos se encaixam):

```
from unicodedata import normalize, combining

def vogal_ou_consoante(letra):
    if len(letra) == 0:
        raise ValueError('string vazia')

    letra = normalize('NFD', letra)

    # se do segundo caractere em diante tiver algum que não é acento
    if not all(combining(c) for c in letra[1:]):
        raise ValueError('string tem mais de um caractere')

    letra = letra[0].lower()
    if letra in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'):
        return True
    elif letra in ('b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'):
        return False
    else:
        raise ValueError('Não é vogal nem consoante')

print(vogal_ou_consoante('á')) # True
print(vogal_ou_consoante('ábaco')) # ValueError
```

Eu uso [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) para verificar se todos os caracteres depois do segundo (`letra[1:]`) são *combining*. Se algum não for, lança o `ValueError`.

---

Claro, isso não significa que a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/318563/112052) está errada. Ela só considerou o caso mais simples - e dada a descrição da pergunta, não ficou claro se precisava ser tão rígido com relação aos critérios, como eu fiz acima. De qualquer forma, ficam aí as opções.

Answer (score 0):

Para complementar as respostas ja postadas, apresento três soluções, uma que contempla vogais "puras" a segunda, vogais "acentuadas", e a terceira retorna se é vogal ou consoante, todas consideram tanto maiúsculas como minúsculas:

## Solução para vogais "puras" (sem acentuação)

```
def is_pure_vowel(c): 
   return True if str.lower(c) in ('a','e','i','o','u') else False
```

## Solução considerando quaisquer vogais ('acentuadas' ou não):

```
$ pip install unidecode

from unidecode import unidecode 
def is_vowel(c): 
   return True if unidecode(str.lower(c)) in ('a','e','i','o','u') else False
```

## Solução para retornar se é vogal ou consoante

```
def vowel_or_consonant(c): 
    if not c.isalpha(): 
       return f'{c} não é uma letra do alfabeto' 
    return 'Vogal' if unidecode(str.lower(c)) in ('a','e','i','o','u') else 'Consoante'
```

Obs.:
As soluções não checam se foi digitado um valor numérico (a não ser que esteja entre aspas), mas isso pode ser contemplado com um simples try.. except.

Answer (score -2):

Consegui solucionar a sua dúvida com o seguinte código:

```
def vogal(v):
    vogais = {'a':'a', 'e':'e', 'i':'i', 'o':'o', 'u':'u'}
    try:
        if vogais[v]:
            print('True')
        else:
            print('False')
    except KeyError:
        print('False')

vogal('b')
```

O código consiste em uma função vogal e que carrega uma variável com o dicionário de vogais. Então, achei que seria uma boa atribuir o tratamento de exceções ao código, porque se você passar uma consoante na na função vogal, ex: `vogal('b')` ele irá retornar um erro de KeyError.

Comment: muito obrigado!!

Comment: tirei a ultima linha porque já apresentava False no inicio, executei o código e ficou show de bola :)

Answer (score -2):

```
def vogal(x):
    y= ['a','e','i','o','u']
    i=0
    prov = []
    for i in y:
        if i == x:
            prov.append(True)
        else:
            prov.append(False)
    if any(prov):
        print('True')
    else:
        print("False")
```

Comment: Olá Gilberto, além de adicionar apenas o código, nós do stackoverflow sugerimos que você o explique, beleza?

Comment: Coloque mais informações sobre a lógica de como o código funciona. Normalmente quem pergunta quer aprender e não somente adquirir uma peça de código.