# Expressão regular que reconheça palavras na língua portuguesa (acentuadas) usando Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Desenvolva a função `frequency()`, que toma uma string como entrada, calcula a frequência de cada palavra na string e retorna um dicionário que mapeia palavras na string à sua frequência. Você deverá usar uma expressão regular (regex) para obter a lista de todas as palavras na string.

O que eu fiz:

```
from re import findall
def frequency(string):
    padrao = "[a-zA-Z]+"
    palavras = findall(padrao,string)
    dicionario = {}
    for w in palavras:
        if w in dicionario:
            dicionario[w] += 1
        else:
            dicionario[w] = 1
    return dicionario


string = "Eu desconfio que houve uma sabotagem, exatamente para manchar a gestão eficiente que está sendo feita na Cedae, preparando ela para o leilão"
print(frequency(string))
```

Saída:

```
{'Eu': 1, 'desconfio': 1, 'que': 2, 'houve': 1, 'uma': 1, 'sabotagem': 1, 'exatamente': 1, 'para': 2, 'manchar': 1, 'a': 1, 'gest': 1, 'o': 3, 'eficiente': 1, 'est': 1, 'sendo': 1, 'feita': 1, 'na': 1, 'Cedae': 1, 'preparando': 1, 'ela': 1, 'leil': 1}
```

Pode-se observar na saída que a expressão regular `[a-zA-Z]+` não reconhece a acentuação das palavras na língua portuguesa.

Como melhorar a regex de forma a capturar as palavras acentuadas corretamente?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uma alternativa é usar o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w`, que em Python 3, por padrão, [já pega letras acentuadas](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-32):

```
from re import findall
def frequency(string):
    palavras = findall(r"\w+", string)
    dicionario = {}
    for w in palavras:
        if w in dicionario:
            dicionario[w] += 1
        else:
            dicionario[w] = 1
    return dicionario


string = "Eu desconfio que houve uma sabotagem, exatamente para manchar a gestão eficiente que está sendo feita na Cedae, preparando ela para o leilão"
print(frequency(string))
```

---

Se bem que `\w` é muito abrangente, pegando inclusive letras de outros alfabetos (como o japonês, árabe, cirílico, etc), além de pegar números e o caractere `_` (ou seja, vai considerar que "123" e "a_b" são palavras).

Se quiser somente as letras, pode usar:

```
palavras = findall(r"[^\W\d_]+", string)
```

Esta é uma [classe de caracteres negados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), e pega tudo que não está entre `[^` e `]`. No caso, temos `\W` (tudo que não for `\w`), `\d` (números) e o próprio caractere `_`. Ou seja, ele pega somente as letras que `\w` já pega, ignorando os números e `_`.

Para ambos os casos acima, a saída é:

```
{'Eu': 1, 'desconfio': 1, 'que': 2, 'houve': 1, 'uma': 1, 'sabotagem': 1, 'exatamente': 1, 'para': 2, 'manchar': 1, 'a': 1, 'gestão': 1, 'eficiente': 1, 'está': 1, 'sendo': 1, 'feita': 1, 'na': 1, 'Cedae': 1, 'preparando': 1, 'ela': 1, 'o': 1, 'leilão': 1}
```

---

#### Detalhe: normalização Unicode

Um adendo, teste com esta string (copie e cole em vez de digitar diretamente):

```
string = "leilão leilão"
print(frequency(string))
```

O resultado será:

```
{'leilão': 1, 'leila': 1, 'o': 1}
```

<sup>*Duvida? [Veja aqui](https://ideone.com/hKSJIW)*</sup>

Isso acontece porque uma das palavras "leilão" está normalizada para a forma NFD. Para mais detalhes sobre o que é isso, sugiro dar uma lida [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/406545/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052), mas basicamente o Unicode define que algumas letras acentuadas podem ter mais de uma forma de serem representadas, sendo que na forma NFD, letras como `ã` são decompostas em 2 caracteres (o `a` e o `~`).

Por isso a regex não consegue mais detectar que é tudo uma palavra só, já que o `~` não é uma letra, nem número, nem `_`, por isso o `\w` ignora este caractere.

Uma solução para este caso seria normalizar para NFC (assim os 2 caracteres são "unidos" em um só, ou seja, o `a` e o `ã` se tornam o `ã`, que a regex consegue detectar):

```
from re import findall
import unicodedata as uc

def frequency(string):
    # normalizar para NFC
    palavras = findall(r"[^\W\d_]+", uc.normalize('NFC', string))
    # o resto da função é igual
```

Não ficou claro de onde vem as strings que a função irá analisar, mas o fato é que é uma possibilidade que elas estejam em NFD (e como você pode ver pelo exemplo acima, visualmente não é possível saber; somente quando o programa for manipular a string é que isso será detectado, podendo dar diferença se não for tratado).

---

Se você quer se limitar a **somente** palavras da língua portuguesa, pode ainda fazer:

```
palavras = findall(r"[a-záéíóúçâêôãõà]+", uc.normalize('NFC', string), re.I)
```

Eu incluí os acentos e a cedilha (nunca vi uma palavra com acento circunflexo no `i`, por isso não coloquei, mas se for o caso é só adicionar). Também usei a [*flag* `re.I`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.I) para que a regex considere tanto letras maiúsculas quanto minúsculas (assim eu não preciso colocar `A-ZÁÉÍ...` na regex).

---

Vale lembrar ainda que na língua portuguesa existem palavras compostas, então o hífen deve ser incluído na regex (mas este deve ter pelo menos algumas letras antes e depois). Uma alternativa seria:

```
palavras = findall(r"[a-záéíóúçâêôãõà]+(?:-[a-záéíóúçâêôãõà]+)*", uc.normalize('NFC', string), re.I)
```

Assim, temos uma sequência de letras (igual ao exemplo anterior), seguido de "hífen + letras", sendo que esta sequência "hífen + letras" pode ocorrer zero ou mais vezes (indicado pelo [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`). Os parênteses usam a sintaxe `(?:` para que este seja um [grupo de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) (sem o `?:`, isto seria um grupo de captura e a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) diz que `findall` retorna somente os grupos quando estes estão presentes - ou seja, retornaria somente o trecho que foi pego pelos parênteses; usando um grupo de não captura eu garanto que todos os *matches* são retornados).

Assim, a string pode ter palavras como "beija-flor" e "pão-de-ló", que elas serão contabilizadas como se fossem uma só (usando as regex anteriores, "beija" e "flor" seriam consideradas palavras separadas).

---

Por fim, para o caso [mencionado nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/431631/express%C3%A3o-regular-que-reconhe%C3%A7a-palavras-na-l%C3%ADngua-portuguesa-acentuadas-usand/431641#comment835891_431637) (que as letras depois do apóstrofo devem ser ignoradas), uma alternativa é:

```
palavras = findall(r"(?<!')[a-záéíóúçâêôãõà]+(?:-[a-záéíóúçâêôãõà]+)*", uc.normalize('NFC', string), re.I)
```

Agora eu uso um [*negative lookbehind*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (o trecho `(?<!')`) que verifica se antes das letras **não** tem um apóstrofo. Assim, ele ignora o "'s" em "Coleridge's" (considerando que apenas "Coleridge" é uma palavra, pois o "s" não será contabilizado e sequer aparecerá nos resultados). Lembrando que sem o *lookbehind*, o "s" é contabilizado como uma palavra separada.

---

Mas se quiser que "Coleridge's" seja uma única palavra, basta usar:

```
palavras = findall(r"[a-záéíóúçâêôãõà]+(?:[-'][a-záéíóúçâêôãõà]+)*", uc.normalize('NFC', string), re.I)
```

A diferença é que agora eu uso `[-']` (um hífen ou apóstrofo) para marcar as palavras "compostas".

Evidentemente que você pode trocar `[a-záéí...]` por `\w` ou `[^\W\d_]`.

---

A desvantagem destas expressões para palavras compostas é que você tem que repetir o trecho que corresponde à letra, mas isso é para garantir que não haverá palavras que começam ou terminam com `'` ou hífen. Mas isso pode ser contornado assim:

```
letras = r"[a-záéíóúçâêôãõà]+"
palavras = findall(f"{letras}(?:[-']{letras})*", uc.normalize('NFC', string), re.I)
```

Assim, você só precisa mudar a definição de "letra" uma vez.

---

Por fim - não diretamente relacionado à regex - você também poderia montar o resultado assim:

```
for w in palavras:
    dicionario[w] = dicionario.get(w, 0) + 1
```

Pois dicionários possuem o [método `get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) que pode opcionalmente retornar um valor *default* caso a chave não exista (no caso, se a chave `w` não existir, retorna zero).

Ou você pode usar um [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), que serve justamente para o que você precisa:

```
from re import findall
import unicodedata as uc
from collections import Counter

def frequency(string):
    letras = r"[a-záéíóúçâêôãõà]+"
    palavras = findall(f"{letras}(?:[-']{letras})*", uc.normalize('NFC', string), re.I)
    return Counter(palavras)
```

Answer (score 4):

A maneira mais fácil de aceitar acentuação é esta:

```
[A-zÀ-ú]+ // aceita caracteres minúsculos e maiúsculos
[A-zÀ-ÿ]+ // como acima, mas incluindo letras com um trema (inclui [] ^ \ × ÷)
[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]+ // como acima, mas sem incluir [] ^ \
[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]+ // como acima, mas sem incluir [] ^ \ ×
```

assim seu código pode ficar:

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from re import findall
def frequency(string):
    padrao = "[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]+"
    palavras = findall(padrao,string)
    dicionario = {}
    for w in palavras:
        if w in dicionario:
            dicionario[w] += 1
        else:
            dicionario[w] = 1
    return dicionario


string = "Eu desconfio que houve uma sabotagem, na gestão exatamente para manchar a gestão eficiente que está sendo feita na Cedae, preparando ela para o leilão"
print(frequency(string))
```

Saída:

```
{'exatamente': 1, 'a': 1, 'feita': 1, 'eficiente': 1, 'sendo': 1, 'para': 2, 'manchar': 1, 'na': 2, 'ela': 1, 'estão': 1, 'o': 1, 'preparando': 1, 'sabotagem': 1, 'houve': 1, 'desconfio': 1, 'uma': 1, 'gestão': 2, 'Eu': 1, 'que': 2, 'Cedae': 1, 'leilão': 1}
```

Exemplo com caracteres especiais no conteúdo do texto:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from re import findall
def frequency(string):
    padrao = "[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ^\']+"
    palavras = findall(padrao,string)
    dicionario = {}
    for w in palavras:
        if w in dicionario:
            dicionario[w] += 1
        else:
            dicionario[w] = 1
    return dicionario


string = "[Coleridge's \"Ancient Mariner.\"]"
print(frequency(string))
```

Saída:

```
{'Mariner': 1, 'Ancient': 1, "Coleridge's": 1}
```

Comment: Não faltou um "+" ao final? testei aqui e pegou letras e nao as palavras

Comment: Sim, atualizei a resposta agora.

Comment: peguei um outro texto em que aparece  [Coleridge's "Ancient Mariner."]   no meio... E agora? Quero so as palavras...

Comment: @EdS Neste caso `Coleridge's` é uma única palavra? Ou "Coleridge" e "s" são "palavras" diferentes?

Comment: @hkotsubo pode ignorar o 's

Comment: @BrunoVdutra: Você esqueceu o "+" ao final das regex de exemplo. Poderia, por favor, editar?

Comment: Você pode usar a seguinte regex [A-Za-zÀ-ÿ^\']+ para desconsiderar o caractere (').

Comment: @EdS Atualizei [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/431641/112052)  com a opção de ignorar o `'s` (e outra opção para considerar "Coleridge's" uma única palavra)

Comment: @EdS atualizei para vc lá.