# Como substituir dois ou mais hífens ou espaços por apenas um hífen

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

Estou montando um blog e preciso de um script para pegar o título do post e gerar um link (sem acentos e espaços), conforme vai escrevendo.

Eu montei esse abaixo, porém não consegui ignorar 2 hífens seguidos, e converter em apenas um:

```js
$("#titulo").keyup(function(){
    var titulo=$(this).val();
    titulo = removerAcentos(titulo);
    $("#previewalias").html(titulo);
})

function removerAcentos(s) {
    var temp = s.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
    temp = temp.toLowerCase();
    return temp.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\ ]/g, "-");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="uk-input uk-form-large" name="titulo" type="text" placeholder="Adicione um título" id="titulo"><br>
<div class="uk-text-muted uk-text-small">Link: <span id="previewalias">/link</span></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a ideia é trocar vários espaços (pelo que entendi do `replace` que já existe) ou vários hífens por um único hífen, basta usar `replace(/[- ]+/g, "-")`.

A [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[- ]` pega um hífen ou um espaço, e o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` pega duas ou mais ocorrências. Assim, se tiver mais de um espaço ou hífen, eles são trocados por um único hífen.

Também não precisa chamar `normalize` duas vezes. A primeira já garantiu que os acentos são removidos, então a string resultante não precisará mais ser normalizada de novo (entenda melhor o que é normalização [lendo aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/406545/112052)).

```js
$("#titulo").keyup(function(){
    var titulo=$(this).val();
    titulo = removerAcentos(titulo);
    $("#previewalias").html(titulo);
})

function removerAcentos(s) {
    return s.normalize('NFD')
        .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
        .toLowerCase()
        .replace(/[- ]+/g, "-");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="uk-input uk-form-large" name="titulo" type="text" placeholder="Adicione um título" id="titulo"><br>
<div class="uk-text-muted uk-text-small">Link: <span id="previewalias">/link</span></div>
```

---

Se bem que o `replace` acima também troca um hífen por outro, o que é meio redundante. Então você pode mudar para trocar um ou mais espaços por um hífen, e depois verificar se há dois ou mais hífens (e trocar por apenas um):

```js
$("#titulo").keyup(function(){
    var titulo=$(this).val();
    titulo = removerAcentos(titulo);
    $("#previewalias").html(titulo);
})

function removerAcentos(s) {
    return s.normalize('NFD')
        .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
        .toLowerCase()
        .replace(/ +/g, "-")
        .replace(/-{2,}/g, "-");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="uk-input uk-form-large" name="titulo" type="text" placeholder="Adicione um título" id="titulo"><br>
<div class="uk-text-muted uk-text-small">Link: <span id="previewalias">/link</span></div>
```