# Normalize ou outra forma de formatar String

Tags: java, string

Tenho este método:

```
public static String trataNomeArquivo(String nomeArquivo) {
    return Normalizer.normalize(nomeArquivo, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "").toUpperCase();
}
```

Ela tira acentos e tudo mais, mas se recebo uma `String` desse tipo por exemplo: `DEMONSTRATIVO DE C301LCULO`, ele não consegue formatar e deixar `DEMONSTRATIVO DE CALCULO`.

Fiz testes com `UrlDecoder` (UTF-8, ISO-8859-1) e não deu certo também.

Comment: O que normalize faz (dependendo da forma adotada) é quebrar o caracter em N outros uma `Ã` vira  `A` e `~` isso é feito pela raiz do codigo unicode um `3` não vai ser um `E`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de falar sobre o seu problema em si, uma pequena introdução sobre [Unicode](http://unicode.org):

#### Normalização

No Unicode, cada caractere* possui um único código numérico (chamado *code point*, leia [este artigo](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) para entender os detalhes). Mas alguns caracteres podem ser representados de maneiras diferentes, definidas pelas de [formas de normalização](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/). Sem entrar em muitos detalhes, *basicamente* significa que alguns caracteres podem ser representados por codepoints diferentes.

Um exemplo é o caractere `Á` (a letra `A` maiúscula com acento agudo), que pode ser representada de duas formas:

1. como o code point [U+00C1](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/c1/index.htm) (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH ACUTE) - no Unicode o valor do code point é representado na forma "U+xxxx", sendo que "xxxx" é o valor em hexadecimal
2. como dois code points:

   - [U+0041](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/41/index.htm) (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A)
   - [U+0301](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/301/index.htm) (COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT)

Podemos ver isso usando código Java. Primeiro eu crio um método que converte uma `String` para determinada forma, e em seguida imprime os code points dela:

```
// converte a String para a forma indicada e imprime os codepoints
public void showCodePoints(String str, Normalizer.Form forma) {
    String s = Normalizer.normalize(str, forma);
    System.out.printf("Code points da string '%s' em %s\n", s, forma);
    s.codePoints().forEach(cp -> {
        System.out.printf(" - U+%04X %s\n", cp, Character.getName(cp));
    });
}
```

Vamos testar este método com `Á`, nas formas NFC e NFD:

```
String s = "Á";
showCodePoints(s, Normalizer.Form.NFC);
showCodePoints(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
```

A saída é:

```
Code points da string 'Á' em NFC
 - U+00C1 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH ACUTE
Code points da string 'Á' em NFD
 - U+0041 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
 - U+0301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
```

Repare que na forma NFC, a `String` só tem o code point U+00C1, e na forma NFD, ela possui os code points U+0041 e U+301. Mas ambas, ao serem impressas, são mostradas como `Á`.

---

#### Tentando descobrir o que aconteceu

Você disse que está recebendo a `String` com o valor `C301LCULO`. Partindo do princípio que o texto original deveria ser `CÁLCULO`, *parece* que por algum motivo a `String` estava em - ou foi convertida para - NFD, mas o `A` se perdeu e chegou apenas o acento - na verdade, o código do acento (U+0301), que foi transformado em texto e colocado na `String`, o que explicaria o `301`.

Então o problema deve estar na origem (em quem gerou e enviou esta `String`). Se puder, investigue o problema lá (e corrija, claro). Senão puder mexer na origem, o jeito é fazer a ["gambiarra"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/365256/112052) mesmo. Sem mais detalhes sobre como a `String` é gerada, é tudo que posso dizer...

---

#### Sobre a sua solução

Na [sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/365256/112052) você usa a regex `"C+[\\d+]+LCULO"`. Vou comentar um pouco sobre ela e sugerir uma melhoria.

O trecho `C+` significa "uma ou mais letras `C`" ([é isso que o `+` significa](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)). Ou seja, se a `String` começar com `CCCCC`, a regex vai aceitar. Se você só quer uma letra `C`, tire o `+` dali.

Já `[\\d+]` não é o que parece. Os colchetes definem uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), ou seja, pegam tudo que estiver dentro deles. Por exemplo, `[ab]` significa "a letra `a` **ou** a letra `b`". Portanto `[\\d+]` significa "um dígito de 0 a 9 (`\d`) **ou** o caractere `+`". Isso acontece porque dentro dos colchetes o `+` "perde os seus poderes" e vira um caractere comum, sem significado especial.

Mas o `+` depois dos colchetes não perdeu seus poderes, então `[\\d+]+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências de dígitos ou `+`". Ou seja, sua regex vai aceitar `Strings` como `CCCC+++++LCULO`. [Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/OhMr4Q/1/) esta regex funcionando.

No caso, você só quer a letra "C" seguida de vários números, então basta usar `C\\d+` ([veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/nm9vAP/1/) a diferença). Outro ponto é que usar `Optional` para verificar a regex me parece meio exagerado. Você pode obter o mesmo resultado com um simples [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

```
public static String trataNomeArquivo(String nomeArquivo) {
    nomeArquivo = nomeArquivo.toUpperCase().replaceAll("C\\d+LCULO", "CALCULO");
    return Normalizer.normalize(nomeArquivo, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
            .replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "").toUpperCase();
}
```

Se a `String` não corresponder à regex `C\\d+LCULO`, o `replaceAll` não faz nenhuma substituição e a `String` não sofre nenhuma modificação, então não há problema em chamá-lo diretamente (não precisa verificar se a regex encontrou um *match*, nem testar se o valor do `Optional` é nulo, etc).

---

É claro que se o código for **sempre** 301, bastaria fazer `replaceAll("C301LCULO", "CALCULO")`.

---

***** O próprio termo "caractere" é um conceito confuso. Muitos acham que um code point é igual a um caractere, mas na verdade é [mais complicado do que isso](https://manishearth.github.io/blog/2017/01/14/stop-ascribing-meaning-to-unicode-code-points/).

Para saber mais sobre Unicode e normalização, leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/406545/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/396555/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/345946/112052).

Answer (score 1):

não tinha me atentado que que esses números não correspondem a nenhuma letra, então provavelmente não tem alguma função do java pra formatar isso.
O que eu fiz, foi uma gambiarra mesmo:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN_CALCULO = Pattern.compile("C+[\\d+]+LCULO");

public static String trataNomeArquivo(String nomeArquivo) {
    String group = Optional.ofNullable(nomeArquivo)
            .map(String::toUpperCase)
            .map(PATTERN_CALCULO::matcher)
            .filter(Matcher::find)
            .map(Matcher::group)
            .orElse(null);

    if(Objects.nonNull(group)) nomeArquivo = nomeArquivo.toUpperCase().replaceAll(group, "CALCULO");

    return Normalizer.normalize(nomeArquivo, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "").toUpperCase();
}
```