# Como validar um field Para aceitar somente Letras/Números usando Regex

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, regex

Estou criando validations para cada property das minhas classes. Estou usando um componente chamado `AbstractValidator`. Exemplo:

```
protected void ValidarChamadaTipo()
{
    RuleFor(p => p.ChamadaTipo)
        .NotNull().WithMessage("Certifique-se de ter informado o Tipo de Chamada");
}
```

Preciso criar duas funções para validar "Aceitar apenas Letras" e "Aceitar apenas Números" usando regex na expressão Lambda.

```
protected void ValidarChamadaTipoSomenteLetras()
{

}

protected void ValidarChamadaTipoSomenteNumeros()
{

}
```

É possível fazer isso? Alguém sabe como fazer?

Comment: Por que não válida com data annotation?

Comment: É que essa validação fica do lado do servidor. Eu consegui validar  do lado do client, mas não sei como usar regex em expressoes regulares.... :(

Comment: Somente números é `^\d+$`, e somente letras é `^\w+$`. Só não coloco uma resposta pq não conheço os detalhes de validations e properties do C#, mas se for somente para usar a regex, é assim: https://ideone.com/KyOqEX

Comment: Na verdade somente letras seria `^[a-zA-Z]+$`

Comment: Obrigado @hkotsubo!!! É isso mesmo!!! Conseguir montar algo com o que achei na net: protected static bool SomenteNumeros(string caracter)
        {
            var rg = new Regex("^[0-9]*$");
            return rg.Match(caracter).Success;
        }

        protected static bool SomenteLetras(string caracter)
        {
            var rg = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
            return rg.Match(caracter).Success;
        }

Comment: Responde lá na pergunta que eu marcarei como resposta!!! :)

Comment: @MasterJR Resposta adicionada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As classes de regex estão no *namespace* [`System.Text.RegularExpressions`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions?view=netframework-4.7.2). Para os seus casos, recomendo usar os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que significam, respectivamente, o início e fim da string. Assim você garante que toda a string só terá o que estiver especificado na expressão.

---

#### Somente Números

Para números, use o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d`, que corresponde a qualquer dígito de 0 a 9. E como a string pode ter vários números, use o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`, que significa "uma ou mais ocorrências". Combinando ambos, temos `\d+`, que significa "um ou mais dígitos".

A expressão completa para verificar se a string só tem dígitos é `^\d+$` (um ou mais dígitos, do início ao fim da string). Se você só quer saber se a string corresponde à regex (apenas `True` ou `False`), pode usar o método [`IsMatch`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("0184784983324", @"^\d+$")); // True
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("a184784983324", @"^\d+$")); // False
```

Você disse nos comentários que usou método `Match`. Ele é útil se você quiser obter mais informações, como o trecho da string que foi capturado, a posição em que ele ocorre, etc. Como nesse caso você só quer saber se a string corresponde à regex, usar `IsMatch` é mais direto.

---

#### Somente Letras

Para letras, uma opção é usar a [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[a-zA-Z]`. Os colchetes representam um conjunto de caracteres. No caso, `[a-zA-Z]` é "qualquer letra de `a` a `z` ou de `A` a `Z`" (qualquer uma delas). Sendo assim, a expressão é `^[a-zA-Z]+$` (uma ou mais letras, do início ao fim da string):

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("abcdeFGHI", @"^[a-zA-Z]+$")); // True
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("abcde9GHI", @"^[a-zA-Z]+$")); // False
```

Só tem um detalhe: esta regex não aceita caracteres acentuados. Uma opção para resolver isso é simplesmente colocar todos os caracteres desejados dentro dos colchetes, algo assim:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("AçãojáJÁ", @"(?i)^[a-záéíóúõãçàâêô]+$")); // True
```

Note que usei `(?i)` no início, que habilita o modo *case insensitive* (ou seja, a regex não diferencia letras maiúsculas e minúsculas). Isso torna o restante da expressão um pouco menor, pois assim só preciso colocar os caracteres uma vez (sem o `(?i)`, eu teria que colocar tanto maiúsculas quanto minúsculas, então ficaria algo como `[a-záéíóúõãçàâêôA-ZÁÉÍÓÚÕÃÇÂÊÔ]`).

Outra alternativa é criar a regex usando o [`RegexOptions`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=netframework-4.7.2) correspondente:

```
// IgnoreCase para não diferenciar maiúsculas e minúsculas
Regex r = new Regex(@"^[a-záéíóúõãçàâêô]+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch("AçãojáJÁ")); // True
```

---

Outra alternativa é usar normalização Unicode para decompor os caracteres acentuados.

No Unicode, cada caractere possui um único código numérico (chamado *code point*, leia [este artigo](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) para entender os detalhes). Mas alguns caracteres podem ser representados de maneiras diferentes, definidas pelas de [formas de normalização](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/). Sem entrar em muitos detalhes, *basicamente* significa que alguns caracteres podem ser representados por *code points* diferentes (veja mais sobre normalização [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/406545/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/396555/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/345946/112052)).

Um exemplo é o caractere `Á` (a letra `A` maiúscula com acento agudo), que pode ser representada de duas formas:

1. como o code point [U+00C1](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/c1/index.htm) (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH ACUTE) - no Unicode o valor do code point é representado na forma "U+xxxx", sendo que "xxxx" é o valor em hexadecimal
2. como dois code points:

   - [U+0041](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/41/index.htm) (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A)
   - [U+0301](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/301/index.htm) (COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT)

Então uma opção é decompor a string para a forma [NFD](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms), que transforma caracteres acentuados para o formato 2 descrito acima (uma letra seguida de um ou mais *combining characters*). Para isso eu uso o método [`Normalize`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.normalize?view=netframework-4.7.2) passando como parâmetro um [`NormalizationForm`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.normalizationform?view=netframework-4.7.2) (disponível no *namespace* [`System.Text`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text?view=netframework-4.7.2)).

Em seguida eu uso a regex `^([a-zA-Z]\p{M}*)+$`:

- `[a-zA-Z]`: uma letra de `a` a `z` (maiúsculas e minúsculas)
- `\p{M}*`: zero ou mais (`*`) caracteres que estejam em uma das 3 categorias Unicode:

  - [Mn](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mn/list.htm) (Mark, Nonspacing)
  - [Mc](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mc/list.htm) (Mark, Spacing Combining)
  - [Me](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Me/list.htm) (Mark, Enclosing)

  Basicamente, os acentos (como o COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT acima) e a cedilha (todos resultantes de quando a string é normalizada para NFD) caem em uma destas categorias.

Sendo assim, este trecho da regex considera qualquer letra de A a Z, seguida ou não de um ou mais caracteres de acentuação. Normalizar para NFD garante que a string estará neste formato.

Por fim, coloco tudo isso entre parênteses, e adiciono o `+` para indicar que isso pode se repetir várias vezes (posso ter várias letras - acentuadas ou não - na regex):

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("AçãojáJÁ".Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD), @"^([a-zA-Z]\p{M}*)+$")); // True
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("Ação8jáJÁ".Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD), @"^([a-zA-Z]\p{M}*)+$")); // False
```

Normalmente "a internet" recomenda usar `\p{L}` em vez de `[a-zA-Z]`. Só que `\p{L}` vai aceitar qualquer letra de qualquer outro idioma (caracteres japoneses, coreanos, árabes, cirílicos, etc), então escolha o que se adequar melhor aos seus casos de uso.