# Extrair conteúdo do campo "Nome:" até o final da linha

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Dada uma string no seguinte formato:

```
'a1in1iionia\n\nDados do cliente\nNome: Foo\nE-mail: foo@bar.com.br\n'
```

Preciso extrair o conteúdo completo do campo "Nome". Para isso, escrevi o código:

```
Nome: ([a-zA-Z]+)
```

O problema é que esse código tem como saída:

> "Nome: Foo"

Embora eu precise somente de `"Foo"`. Além disso, percebi que essa seleção não funciona para o caso de nome composto. Sem entrar em expressões regulares para nomes completos, preciso que a seleção deste campo termine em `'\n'`, ou seja, no final da linha.

Como tornar minha expressão mais robusta para esses casos?

Comment: Estou usando Python3.x e testando através do site https://regex101.com/

Comment: Essa regex está certa, mas você tem que utilizar o que está no grupo 1 e não a captura completa. Qual o código python que está usando ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depende de como está a sua string.

Se depois de `"Nome: "` só tem o nome e logo depois a quebra de linha, o mais simples é usar:

```
import re

s = 'a1in1iionia\n\nDados do cliente\nNome: Foo\nE-mail: foo@bar.com.br\n'
result = re.findall(r'Nome: (.+)', s)
print(result)
```

Estou me aproveitando de três fatos:

- Por padrão, o ponto (`.`) considera [qualquer caractere, exceto quebras de linha](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-0)
- O [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` (uma ou mais ocorrências) é [ganancioso](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) e tenta pegar o máximo de caracteres que puder. Por isso, `.+` pega tudo até a próxima quebra de linha
- Os parênteses formam um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), e [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) retorna uma lista com os grupos de captura, quando estes estão presentes

O resultado é uma lista com o nome:

> ['Foo']

Você pode pegar o nome com `result[0]`, se quiser. A regex funciona para nomes com espaços e vários sobrenomes.

Outra alternativa é usar [`search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search):

```
import re

s = 'a1in1iionia\n\nDados do cliente\nNome: Foo\nE-mail: foo@bar.com.br\n'
match = re.search(r'Nome: (.+)', s)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

Com isso eu obtenho o que foi capturado no grupo de captura, usando o método [`group`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group) (como o nome está dentro do primeiro par de parênteses da regex, então ele é o grupo 1, por isso eu faço `match.group(1)`). A diferença para `findall` é que agora eu já tenho o nome como uma string (em vez de uma lista). O resultado é:

> Foo

De qualquer forma, sua regex também estava correta, o único detalhe é que você não estava pegando o grupo de captura, e sim **todo** o trecho correspondente ao *match*.

Se quiser, também pode usar um [*lookbehind*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) para verificar se existe o trecho `"Nome: "`:

```
import re

s = 'a1in1iionia\n\nDados do cliente\nNome: Foo\nE-mail: foo@bar.com.br\n'
match = re.search(r'(?<=Nome: ).+', s)
if match:
    print(match.group())
```

A diferença é que o *lookbehind* (o trecho entre `(?<=` e `)`) só verifica se algo existe antes da posição atual, mas ele não fará parte do *match*. Por isso não preciso mais do grupo de captura e o resultado do código acima é a string `Foo` (veja no [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pnc8Lz/1/)).

Mas sinceramente, eu acho desnecessário nesse caso. Usar o *lookbehind* deixa a regex um pouco mais complicada e ineficiente. [Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/pnc8Lz/1/debugger) um *debug* da regex com *lookbehind* e [compare com a regex sem *lookbehind*](https://regex101.com/r/P1EeiZ/2/debugger) (veja a quantidade de passos que cada uma leva). Usar *lookbehind* deixa a regex mais lenta porque ela precisa voltar o tempo todo para verificar se tem o trecho `"Nome: "` antes da posição atual. É claro que para strings pequenas e rodando poucas vezes, a diferença será insignificante (talvez milissegundos ou até menos), mas é importante ter isso em mente: vale a pena usar uma regex um pouco mais complicada e lenta, só para não ter que usar o grupo de captura?

Enfim, nos exemplos abaixo usarei `findall` e sem o *lookbehind* (ou seja, usarei o grupo de captura), mas as mesmas regex também funcionam com `search`. Use o que achar melhor.

---

#### Validar o nome

O problema é que o ponto vai aceitar qualquer coisa (inclusive caracteres especiais, como `@!#$%^&`, entre outros, que não necessariamente fazem parte de um nome).

Se quiser, pode restringir mais a string para aceitar somente uma sequência de letras, espaço, letras, espaço, etc... Ficaria assim:

```
import re

s = 'a1in1iionia\n\nDados do cliente\nNome: Fulano de Tal\nE-mail: foo@bar.com.br\n'
result = re.findall(r'Nome: ([a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+)*)', s)
print(result)
```

Saída:

> ['Fulano de Tal']

Agora a regex é `([a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+)*)`:

- a primeira parte é `[a-zA-Z]+`: uma ou mais letras (maiúsculas ou minúsculas)
- em seguida, temos `(?:`, que cria um [grupo de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) (assim ele não é retornado por `findall`, pois estou interessado somente no grupo mais externo, que contém todo o nome)

  - dentro deste grupo temos um espaço (há um espaço entre o `:` e o `[`), seguido de várias letras
  - todo esse grupo (espaço mais letras) pode se repetir zero ou mais vezes (indicado pelo `*`). Isso garante que podemos ter zero ou mais sobrenomes

---

#### Melhorias

Claro que ainda dá para melhorar mais. Se quiser que o nome comece sempre com letra maiúscula, pode usar `[A-Z][a-z]+`. A regex também não inclui nomes com apóstrofo (ex: "D'aquino") ou com hífen, nem caracteres acentuados.

Para os acentos, alguns podem sugerir `\w` em vez de `[a-zA-Z]`, mas o problema é que este atalho também aceita números e o caractere `_`, então eu não usaria se quisesse mais precisão. Uma alternativa é usar algo do tipo:

```
re.findall(r'Nome: ([a-záéíóúâêôçãõ]+(?: [a-záéíóúâêôçãõ]+)*)', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Com isso, todas as letras acentuadas fazem parte do nome, e a opção [`IGNORECASE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE) faz com que maiúsculas e minúsculas sejam consideradas (assim eu não preciso colocar `ÁÉÍÓÚ....` na regex).

---

Outra opção é usar o [módulo `regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), uma excelente extensão do módulo `re` nativo. Você pode instalá-lo com `pip install regex`.

Este módulo possui suporte à propriedades Unicode, então eu posso usar `\p{L}` para qualquer caractere que seja uma letra.

Eu também uso o [módulo `unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html) para normalizar a string, garantindo que ela não quebrará a regex (normalização Unicode está além do escopo aqui, mas você pode ler mais a respeito [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/406545/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/396555/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/345946/112052)).

```
import regex
import unicodedata

s = 'a1in1iionia\n\nDados do cliente\nNome: Fulâno D\'aquino Ávila Souza-e-Silva\nE-mail: foo@bar.com.br\n'
# regex para um nome ou sobrenome
nome = r'\p{L}+(?:[-\']\p{L}+)*'
# cria a regex (nome, espaço, sobrenome, espaço, sobrenome...)
r = regex.compile(r'Nome: ({0}(?: {0})*)'.format(nome))
result = r.findall(unicodedata.normalize('NFC', s))
print(result)
```

Eu também incluí a verificação de apóstrofo ou hífen no nome: `(?:[-\']\p{L}+)*` é um hífen ou apóstrofo, seguido de várias letras (e o asterisco faz esse grupo todo se repetir zero ou mais vezes).

A saída é:

> ["Fulâno D'aquino Ávila Souza-e-Silva"]

Lembrando que `\p{L}` também inclui, além dos caracteres acentuados, letras de outros idiomas, como japonês, árabe, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a flag [`re.MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) que serve justamente para procurar texto em múltiplas linhas de forma simplificada:

```
>>> import re    
>>> texto = 'a1in1iionia\n\nDados do cliente\nNome: Foo\nE-mail: foo@bar.com.br\n'
>>> m = re.search('Nome: (.*)$', texto, re.MULTILINE)
>>> print(m.group(1))
Foo
```

Dessa forma ao usar `re.MULTILINE` o sinal de `$` na expressão regular passa a significar *"fim-de-linha"*; com isso fica fácil pegar todo o texto até o final da linha