# Quantidade de vogais na função do Python

Tags: python, string

Quero fazer uma função no Python que faça uma **contagem de quantas vogais há em uma string em que o usuário digita.**

Meu código:

```
def cacavogais():
    i = 0
    j = 0
    string = str (input("Digite alguma coisa: "))
    for i in string:
        if i.lower() in string:
             j+=1
    print ("A string digitada foi: {}".format(string))
    print ("A quantidade de vogais que possui é {}".format(j))

cacavogais()
```

Comment: E qual é o erro Alex? Aparentemente não parece haver nada errado. Você só não está printando `j`, mas parece estar contando normalmente.

Comment: Eita porr#$%, vou testa aqui.

Comment: Alex, `string[i]` não faz sentido, pois `i` vai ser cada letra da string. Então é mais fácil simplesmente usar o operador `in`. Tipo assim: `if i.lower() in "aeiou":`

Comment: Deu muito certo não, aparentemente não apresenta o número de vogais esperadas, vou editar meu código.

Comment: Vou criar uma resposta com a explicação. Só código pronto não vai te ajudar a entender o conceito.

Comment: Não vai ser necessário já postaram a resposta que queria e agora entendi o que estava errado, obrigado mesmo assim.

Comment: Fernando, excelente, poste pois poderá ajudar outra pessoa que por venture passe pelo mesmo problema. :)

Comment: OK, se tu já sabe o que é o `str.lower()` e já conhece o operador `in` tudo bem...

Comment: Beleza, Filipe.. vou postar igual então...

Comment: Tá @fernandosavio.

Comment: Postado... Qualquer dúvida é só comentar na resposta...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
def cacavogais():
    i = 0
    j = 0
    string = str (input("Digite alguma coisa: "))
    for i in string:
        if (i == 'A' or i == 'a'
        or i == 'E' or i == 'e'
        or i == 'I' or i == 'i'
        or i == 'O' or i == 'o'
        or i == 'U' or i == 'u'):
             j+=1
    print("vogais: ", j)

cacavogais()
```

Mas tem jeitos melhores de fazer, de uma lida [aqui](https://www.journaldev.com/23610/python-string-equals).
Uma outra forma de fazer isso seria assim, por exemplo:

```
def cacavogais():
    i = 0
    j = 0
    string = str (input("Digite alguma coisa: "))
    string = string.lower()
    for i in string:
        if (i == 'a'
        or i == 'e'
        or i == 'i'
        or i == 'o'
        or i == 'u'):
             j+=1
    print("vogais: ", j)

cacavogais()
```

Answer (score 4):

Uma maneira de resolver é usar uma [*list comprehension*](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) (bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052)):

```py
vogais = 'aeiou'
s = 'abcdefghijABCEx'
qtd_vogais = len([c for c in s.lower() if c in vogais])
print(qtd_vogais) # 5
```

A linha `qtd_vogais = len([c for c in s.lower() if c in vogais])` é equivalente ao *loop* sugerido pelas outras respostas:

```py
vogais = 'aeiou'
s = 'abcdefghijABCEx'
qtd_vogais = 0
for c in s.lower():
    if c in vogais:
        qtd_vogais += 1

print(qtd_vogais) # 5
```

Basicamente, [`s.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) transforma a string em letras minúsculas, e `for c in s.lower()` faz um *loop* por todos os caracteres da string. A cada iteração, `c` será um caractere. Então basta testar se `c` é uma vogal e incrementar o contador.

No caso da *list comprehension*, é criada uma [lista](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) com todas as vogais (pois a expressão está dentro de colchetes), e a função [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) retorna o tamanho desta lista.

---

Se quiser considerar também caracteres acentuados, pode usar o [módulo `unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/unicodedata.html):

```py
from unicodedata import normalize

vogais = 'aeiou'
s = 'ábcdefghijABCEx'
qtd_vogais = len([c for c in normalize('NFD', s.lower()) if c in vogais])
print(qtd_vogais) # 5
```

De maneira bem resumida, a [normalização](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) em NFD "quebra" o "á" em dois caracteres: o `a` (sem acento) e o próprio acento. Assim, é possível verificar as vogais da mesma forma feita anteriormente. (tem uma explicação mais detalhada sobre a normalização [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/406545/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/396555/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/345946/112052) - apesar de não ser em Python, a ideia é a mesma)

---

Outra opção é usar um [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
from unicodedata import normalize

vogais = 'aeiou'
s = 'ábcdefghijABCEx'
c = Counter(normalize('NFD', s.lower()))
qtd_vogais = sum(qtd for letra, qtd in c.items() if letra in vogais)
print(qtd_vogais) # 5
```

O `Counter`  resultante é um [dicionário](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict), cujas chaves são os caracteres da string e os valores são a quantidade de vezes que cada caractere ocorre na string.

Então basta percorrê-lo, ver quais chaves são vogais e somar as quantidades.

Comment: +1 pela normalização de Unicode... é sempre bom. :)

Answer (score 2):

Para contar vogais seguiremos os seguintes passos:

1. Ler uma string digitada pelo usuário
2. Ler letra por letra da string digitada pelo usuário
3. Checar se esta letra é uma vogal (pra fins didático ignoraremos acentos)
4. Se for uma vogal, incrementamos um contador
5. Após ler a palavra toda, mostraremos o conteúdo do contador

---

### Passo a passo

1. **Ler uma string digitada pelo usuário**

   Usaremos o método [`str.input()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#input) para receber a string do usuário

   ```
   palavra = input("Digite uma palavra: ")
   ```
2. **Ler letra por letra da string digitada pelo usuário**

   Usaremos o [`for`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) para iterar sobre cada letra da palavra digitada.

   ```
   for letra in palavra:
       # ...
   ```
3. **Checar se esta letra é uma vogal** (pra fins didático ignoraremos acentos)

   Usaremos um [`if`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#if) para testar se a letra é uma vogal ou não.

   Para isso testaremos se a letra existe dentro da string `"aeiouAEIOU"`, se ela existir é uma vogal (maiúscula ou minúscula).

   ```
   for letra in palavra:
       if letra in "aeiouAEIOU":
           # ...
   ```
4. **Se for uma vogal, incrementamos um contador**

   ```
   contador = 0
   for letra in palavra:
       if letra in "aeiouAEIOU":
           contador += 1
   ```
5. **Após ler a palavra toda, mostraremos o conteúdo do contador**

   ```
   print("A palavra '{}' tem {} vogais.".format(palavra, contador))
   ```

---

O código final ficará:

```
palavra = input("Digite uma palavra: ")
contador = 0

for letra in palavra:
    if letra in "aeiouAEIOU":
        contador += 1

print("A palavra '{}' tem {} vogais.".format(palavra, contador))
```

<sup>[Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-380922-6333) com o código rodando</sup>

---

### Extra

Você pode usar a função [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=len#len) e [*list-comprehensions*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) para fazer a mesma coisa, porém com o código mais enxuto:

```
palavra = input("Digite uma palavra: ")
contador = len([letra for letra in palavra if letra in "aeiouAEIOU"])
print("A palavra '{}' tem {} vogais.".format(palavra, contador))
```

Answer (score 1):

Alex, siga o exemplo abaixo que resolve seu problema.

```
def contarVogais(a):
    vogais = "aeuioAEUIO"
    result = 0
    for char in a:
        if char in vogais:
            result = result + 1
    return result

contarVogais("ajdgejfifhou")
```

Espero ter ajudado.