# Como desactivar renderização de emoji dentro de uma tag HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho uma plataforma ([Web site](https://eventos.ubi.co.mz/) ) onde qualquer indivíduo pode criar conteúdos (imagens e textos), entretanto gostaria de ***controlar a renderização*** de **Símbolos HTML** em específicos os **Emoji** dentro de uma tag em específico (neste caso, `div`).

- ***Controlar renderização de emoji*** - Filtrar (*Remover, Esconder, desactivar a renderização*) todos os símbolos, códigos dos emoji e deixar apenas os textos.
- **O HTML**

```html
<div class="title-content" style="padding-top:0">
  <h2 class="title" style="padding-top:0">      </h2>
</div>
```

- **A Imagem**

[image: Renderização do código HTML com emoji na página]

**Formulário de criação do conteúdo**

- **Input do título**

  ```
  <div class="ubi-agenda-form-group col-xs-12">
    <label for="title" class="label-control">
      Titulo
      <span class="symbol required"></span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="input-control " autocomplete='name' id="title" required="required" name="title" placeholder="Ex: Noites de Pandza">
  </div>
  ```
- **Submit do Formulário - jQuery**

```
let titulo = $('input#title').val(); // Busco aqui o input antes de enviar para base de dados

let tituloTratado = tratarTitulo(title); // a tal funcao em javascript/Jquery para remover os símbolos, códigos dos emoji e deixar apenas os textos.
```

Comment: Sim! Sem os emojis e a respeitar a `font-family` da tag

Comment: Se for possivel alterar antes de guardar no Banco de dados seria bom.

Comment: @MauroAlmeida fiz algumas alteraçôes na pergunta para tentar deixar ela mais clara.

Comment: Já respondi em baixo, espero que ajude ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nos [comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/396850/como-desactivar-renderiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-emoji-dentro-de-uma-tag-html#comment779942_396853) você disse que quer tirar a formatação (a string "  " deveria se tornar "Meu time Anonimo").

O problema é que esta string que você está usando não é exatamente um texto formatado. Não no sentido de ter alguma tag HTML formatando-o. Na verdade, este texto está usando outros caracteres diferentes das letras do nosso alfabeto:

```js
let s = "  ";
// imprimir os code points da string
console.log(Array.from(s).map(c => c.codePointAt(0).toString(16)));
```

No código acima, estou imprimindo os code points. Para entender os detalhes sobre code points, [sugiro esta - longa - leitura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052), mas resumidamente, cada caractere existente (sejam letras, números, espaços, sinais de pontuação, símbolos matemáticos, etc) possui um valor numérico único, determinado pelo [Unicode](http://unicode.org/).

Se você rodar o código acima, verá que os primeiros elementos do array são os code points  "1d474" e "1d486" (os valores foram impressos em hexadecimal). O primeiro corresponde ao [caractere "MATHEMATICAL BOLD ITALIC CAPITAL M"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d474/index.htm), que é a letra "M" maiúscula "estilizada" em itálico e negrito. Já o segundo é o [caractere "MATHEMATICAL BOLD ITALIC SMALL E"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d486/index.htm).

Eles são caracteres diferentes das letras "M" (cujo code point é [U+004D](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/004d/index.htm)) e "e" (code point [U+0065](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0065/index.htm)). Os caracteres "" e "", embora sejam visualmente parecidos com as letras "M" e "e", não são os mesmos caracteres, pois possuem code points diferentes. E mais importante, por mais que pareçam apenas um "M" e um "e" formatados, eles não são exatamente isso. Pois se você escrever "", sem nenhuma formação, eles já estarão assim, em "itálico e negrito", mas se você aplicar esta formatação, eles ficarão ainda "mais itálicos e negritos" ([veja este exemplo no Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZAesa4mrwP_2B2OzuMowDaVkqCs4GNNHe327gQT2JQA/edit)):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O mesmo exemplo em HTML:

```html
<!-- Caracteres ASCII -->
<p>Meu TIME Anonimo</p>
<p><b><i>Meu TIME Anonimo</i></b></p>
<!-- Caracteres Unicode (Mathematical Letters) -->
<p>  </p>
<p><b><i>  </i></b></p>
```

Repare como eles são renderizados de forma diferente. Os caracteres Unicode, mesmo sem nenhuma formatação, já estão "em negrito e itálico" mesmo sem tags `<b>` e `<i>`, e com as tags, eles ficam ainda "mais negritos e itálicos" (mais "grossos" e "inclinados").

Sendo assim, você não quer exatamente "tirar a formatação", e sim converter estes caracteres para os seus equivalentes em ASCII. Para fazer isso, você pode usar o método [`normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize):

```js
let s = "  ".normalize('NFKC');
console.log(s);
// imprimir os code points da string
console.log(Array.from(s).map(c => c.codePointAt(0).toString(16)));
```

Repare que agora o texto foi impresso com os caracteres ASCII ("sem formatação"): `Meu TIME Anonimo`, e os primeiros code points são "4d" e "65", que correspondem às letras "M" e "e".

Você pode aplicar a normalização depois de remover os emojis (usando a [solução proposta pelo MauroAlmeida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/396853/112052)), assim seu texto ficará "limpo" da maneira que você precisa.

Para entender um pouco mais sobre a normalização Unicode, leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/406545/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/396555/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/345946/112052) - e mais detalhes podem ser encontrados no [documento do Unicode que descreve a normalização](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/).

Comment: Excelente! Era exatamente isso que estava a procura

Answer (score 5):

Fiz aqui um **mini exemplo** de como remover do texto os `emojis` usando [regex](https://www.regextester.com/106421).

Para testar pode introduzir os `emojis` e clicar no botão `Clique para retirar emojis` e verá que na segunda caixa de texto os `emojis` não aparecem.

Pode guardar no banco de dados a `string` retornada do `replace`.

```js
$('#button').click( function() {
  var text = $('#title').val();
  text = text.replace(/(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])/g, '').normalize('NFKC');
  $('#result').val(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="title" name="title"><br>
<input type="button" id="button" name="button" value="Clique para retirar emojis"><br>
<input type="text" id="result" name="result"><br>
```

**Editada**: Usando a function `normalize` como descrito por [hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/396881/49505)

Comment: Obrigado @MauroAlmeida!.  O regex funciona, mas tem um problema não formata o texto; ou seja, além de aparecer assim  `Meu Time anonimo` ele continua aparecer assim `  `