# Inverter as palavras de uma frase, mantendo a ordem delas na frase

Tags: python, string

Fiz esse algoritmo em Python para inverter uma frase, de certa forma deu certo, mas preciso que ela inverta a frase mantendo a ordem das palavras.

Por exemplo: `OI TUDO BEM` teria de ficar `IO ODUT MEB`, no entanto ela está invertendo a frase da seguinte forma: `MEB ODUT IO`. Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Meu código em Python:

```
frase = str(input('Digite uma frase: '))
print(' Você digitou: {}'.format(frase))
string = frase[::-1]
print('A frase que você digitou invertida fica: {}'.format(string))
```

Comment: Você pode aplicar o `split()` e depois inverter cada elemento do array gerado e  assim só imprimir

Comment: Eu tentei usar o split(), mas foi justamente o que não consegui, ele imprime a frase cm as palavras separadas por aspas e não inverte a ordem das letras, somente a ordem das palavras, eu nao entendi justamente como eu teria de usar ele.

Answer (score 4):

Isso acontece porque todo o conteúdo da `frase` é invertido, já que o [*slice*](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.3.html#extended-slices) `[::-1]` opera sobre toda a string. Se quer que cada palavra da frase seja invertida individualmente, você precisa separar a frase em palavras, inverter cada palavra e depois juntá-las.

Para isso, basta usar o [método `split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) para separar a frase em palavras. Assumindo que as palavras estão separadas apenas por espaços, basta chamar o método sem argumentos (`frase.split()`), que ele retornará uma lista de strings, na qual cada elemento é uma das palavras.

Depois você inverte cada palavra individualmente e junta-as novamente. Você pode fazer um loop tradicional, conforme a [resposta do Jean](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401491/112052) (embora a solução dele deixe um espaço a mais no final), mas também pode usar o [método `join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), juntamente com uma [*list comprehension*](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), que é uma forma bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052):

```
frase = input('Digite uma frase: ')
print(' Você digitou: {}'.format(frase))
invertida = ' '.join(palavra[::-1] for palavra in frase.split())
print('A frase que você digitou invertida fica: {}'.format(invertida))
```

No caso, o `join` junta os elementos da lista, usando o espaço (`' '`) como separador. O trecho `palavra[::-1] for palavra in frase.split()` dentro do `join` é a *list comprehension*, que é uma outra forma de escrever um loop similar ao da [resposta do Jean](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401491/112052). Basicamente, para cada palavra resultante do `split`, é feita a inversão desta individualmente, e no fim o `join` junta todas elas.

Repare também que a [função `input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) já retorna uma string, então não precisa chamar `str(input(...))`, é redundante.

---

Poderíamos parar por aqui, mas tem um detalhe nesta implementação. Se tivermos uma frase como o exemplo abaixo:

```
frase = 'Oi, tudo bem?     Blablabla'
invertida = ' '.join(palavra[::-1] for palavra in frase.split())
print(invertida)
```

O resultado é:

```
,iO odut ?meb albalbalB
```

Repare que a vírgula e o ponto de interrogação também foram invertidos (pois a divisão foi feita pelos espaços, então os caracteres `,` e `?` foram considerados parte das palavras. E os vários espaços antes de "Blablabla" foram trocados por apenas um. Isso acontece porque o `split` separou por vários espaços, mas no `join` eu só usei um (este caso daria para resolver usando `frase.split(' ')`, mas a vírgula e o ponto de interrogação continuariam fazendo parte da inversão).

Neste caso você poderia usar expressões regulares (regex), através do [módulo `re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). Uma expressão regular também possui o [método `split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split), mas ele pode usar critérios mais complexos, que permitem tratar estes casos:

```
import re

def inverte(palavra):
    if re.match(r'^\w+$', palavra):
        return palavra[::-1]
    return palavra

frase = 'Oi, tudo bem?     Blablabla'
invertida = ''.join(inverte(palavra) for palavra in re.split(r'(\W+)', frase))
print(invertida)
```

No `split` usei `(\W+)`. O `\W` é um [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) para "caractere não-alfanumérico" (qualquer coisa que **não** seja letra, número ou `_`). O `+` é um [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) que significa "uma ou mais ocorrências". Ou seja, estou separando a frase não só por espaços, mas por quaisquer caracteres não-alfanuméricos.

Além disso, [os parênteses formam um grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). E quando há grupos de captura na regex, os separadores também são retornados na lista. Assim eu não perco os valores originais que a frase tinha (a lista retornada pelo `split` terá as palavras e os separadores), e consigo restaurá-los na hora de juntar tudo no final.

Em seguida, eu uso a *list comprehension*, mas com uma função auxiliar que criei para saber se o que eu tenho é de fato uma palavra, ou um separador (a vírgula, o `?`, os espaços, etc). Para isso eu uso `^\w+$`: os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` são respectivamente o início e fim da string, e `\w+` é "um ou mais caracteres alfanuméricos".

Sendo assim, se for uma palavra (se só tiver caracteres alfanuméricos do início ao fim da string), eu inverto. Senão, deixo como está.

No fim, junto tudo com `join` (mas agora usei a string vazia `''` em vez do espaço `' '`). O resultado é:

```
iO, odut meb?     albalbalB
```

Agora só as palavras foram invertidas. Os espaços e pontuações foram mantidos intactos.

---

Claro que sempre dá para complicar mais. Se a string tiver emojis, ou até mesmo alguns caracteres acentuados, dependendo do caso, uma simples inversão como essa pode não funcionar. Aí talvez já fuja demais do escopo da pergunta, mas é interessante dar uma olhada [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/345946/112052) para entender mais detalhes sobre estes casos (apesar da resposta ser em Java, há alguns conceitos mais gerais sobre o Unicode, que se aplicam a outras linguagens, inclusive Python).

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o método `split` para separar cada palavra da string e depois inverta elas. Exemplo:

```
new_string = ""
frase = input('Digite uma frase: ') #A função input retorna sempre uma string
print(' Você digitou: {}'.format(frase))
for palavra in frase.split(" "):
    new_string += palavra[::-1]+" "
print('A frase que você digitou invertida fica: {}'.format(new_string))
```

Comment: Nossa, cara, valeu, estava quebrando a cabeça com esse algoritmo, e agora entendi certinho como faz, muito obrigado!

Comment: Que bom que eu consegui lhe ajudar ;)

Comment: Entendeu o `split()` kkkkkl