# Expressão Regular para caracteres alfanuméricos, hífen, espaço ou aspas simples

Tags: java, regex

Estou procurando uma regex que aceita caracteres alfa-numéricos, espaços, `'` e `-`.

Esses exemplos devem ser aceitos: `"Jean-da Silva"`, `"Carlos 2"`, `"João d'lango"`.

Exemplos não aceitos: `"J@ão"`, `"Carlos*"`.

Comment: Igor, atualizei a resposta (tinha faltado um `break` no `for` - no segundo bloco de código)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma alternativa ("simplista" e "ingênua" - já vamos entender porquê) seria:

```
String[] v = { "Jean-da Silva", "Carlos 2", "João d'lango", "J@ão", "Carlos*", "teste_1" };
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^[-\\w' &&[^_]]+$", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS).matcher("");
for (String s : v) {
    matcher.reset(s);
    System.out.println(s + "=" + (matcher.find() ? "válida" : "inválida"));
}
```

A regex usa uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (delimitada pelos colchetes `[]`).

Dentro desta classe de caracteres, temos um hífen, o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w` (que corresponde a letras, números e o caractere `_`), a "aspas simples" `'` e um espaço (repare que tem um espaço entre o `'` e o `&`). Como o `\w` também pega o caractere `_`, eu uso a [sintaxe de intersecção (`&&`)](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-class-operations.html#subtraction) com uma [classe de caracteres negada](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) (o `[^_]`, que exclui o `_` deste grupo).

Depois eu uso o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`, que significa "uma ou mais ocorrências". Ou seja, eu posso ter um ou mais caracteres da lista (letras, números, hífen, `'` ou espaço). Por fim, eu uso os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que significam respectivamente o início e fim da string. Assim, eu garanto que a string só vai ter esses caracteres.

Só que, por *default*, o comportamento do atalho `\w` é [não considerar caracteres acentuados](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#predef). Então eu também uso a opção [`UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS), para que o `\w` também pegue as letras com acento.

A saída é:

```
Jean-da Silva=válida
Carlos 2=válida
João d'lango=válida
J@ão=inválida
Carlos*=inválida
teste_1=inválida
```

Eu também poderia ter usado algo como `[0-9a-záéíóúãõâêîôû]` para pegar todos os acentos (e aí você acrescenta todos os caracteres que desejar nos colchetes, como a `ç`, `ñ`, e quaisquer outros que precisar). Mas `\w` com a opção `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` já abrange todos esses caracteres (no final veremos algumas ressalvas sobre esta solução).

---

Mas como eu disse, essa regex é ingênua. Se a string for `"---"`, `"' -"`, ou só tiver espaços, ela também é considerada válida.

Uma alternativa um pouco melhor seria quebrar a string pelos separadores (espaço, `'` ou hífen) e verificar se cada uma das partes só tem letras e números:

```
String[] v = { "Jean-da Silva", "Carlos 2", "João d'lango", "J@ão", "Carlos*", "teste_1", "---", "' -" };
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^[\\w&&[^_]]+$", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS).matcher("");
for (String s : v) {
    boolean valida = false;
    // quebrar pelos separadores
    for (String parte : s.split("[-' ]")) {
        matcher.reset(parte);
        valida = matcher.find();
        if (!valida) // se encontrou um inválido, pode sair do loop
            break;
    }
    System.out.println(s + "=" + (valida ? "válida" : "inválida"));
}
```

Agora eu uso [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) para quebrar a string em partes.

No `split` eu uso `[-' ]` como o delimitador, indicando que eu quero separar a string pelos hífens, espaços ou `'` (repare que tem um espaço entre o `'` e o `]`). O resultado é um array contendo as partes da string depois de separadas.

Depois, para cada parte, eu verifico se ela corresponde a `^[\\w&&[^_]]+$` (letras ou números, do início ao fim da string). Eu continuo usando a opção `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` para que o `\w` pegue caracteres acentuados, e uso a intersecção `&&[^_]` para que ela não considere o `_`.

A saída é:

```
Jean-da Silva=válida
Carlos 2=válida
João d'lango=válida
J@ão=inválida
Carlos*=inválida
teste_1=inválida
---=inválida
' -=inválida
```

Outra alternativa seria usar as propriedades Unicode:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^[\\p{L}\\p{N}]+$", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS).matcher("");
// for com split, igual ao código anterior
```

Nesse caso, a regex considera apenas os caracteres que são letras, incluindo as acentuadas (`\p{L}`) ou números (`\p{N}`).

---

Um detalhe das opções acima é que elas são bem abrangentes e também consideram caracteres que talvez você não queira.

Quando a opção `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` é usada, o `\w` também considera [outros caracteres](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#predef_classes), como por exemplo aqueles que possuem a propriedade `Join_Control` (que no caso são o [ZERO WIDTH NON JOINER](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm) e o [ZERO WIDTH JOINER](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200d/index.htm)), além de vários outros caracteres. E o `\p{L}` considera letras de outros alfabetos, como o japonês e o árabe, por exemplo.

Se não quiser ser tão abrangente, uma alternativa é usar [`java.text.Normalizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/text/Normalizer.html) juntamente com outra regex para eliminar os acentos, e buscar apenas por letras de `a` a `z` e números de 0 a 9:

```
// opção CASE_INSENSITIVE para considerar letras maiúsculas e minúsculas
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^[a-z0-9]+$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher("");
for (String s : v) {
    boolean valida = false;
    for (String parte : s.split("[-' ]")) {
        // elimina os acentos
        matcher.reset(Normalizer.normalize(parte, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{M}", ""));
        valida = matcher.find();
        if (!valida) // se encontrou um inválido, pode sair do loop
            break;
    }
    System.out.println(s + "=" + (valida ? "válida" : "inválida"));
}
```

De forma bem resumida, a normalização para a forma NFD "quebra" um caractere acentuado em dois. Por exemplo, o `ã` é quebrado em `a` e `~`. (para mais detalhes sobre normalização, leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/406545/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/396555/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/345946/112052)).

Em seguida `\p{M}` serve para remover os caracteres correspondentes aos acentos (os chamados [*combining diacritical marks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks)). No final, sobram somente as letras, sem os acentos, que posso buscar com `^[a-z0-9]+$` (graças à opção [`CASE_INSENSITIVE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE), ela já pega tanto letras maiúsculas quanto minúsculas).

Answer (score -1):

Regex abaixo aceita apenas caracteres, numeros e os caracteres especiais "'" e "-"

```
[a-zA-Z0-9 '-]
```

Comment: testei no https://regexr.com/ e funcionou, o Z-Z, realmente o 0 ta faltando vou editar, para feito de melhor leitura do regex, alterei o Z-Z para A-Z

Comment: Só o `Z-Z` sozinho não funciona, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/kTX6oY/1/)

Comment: pegadinha do https://regexr.com/