# Usando Pilha, como posso verificar se uma string é o inverso de outra?

Tags: java, estrutura-de-dados

EX:
 x = "ABABBA" e y= ABBABA

Eu já fiz a classe `Pilha`, com os métodos, porém estou com dúvida como implementar.

```
package questao02;
public class Pilha<T> {
    T[]arrayelem;
    int topo;
    int index = 0;
    public Pilha(int max){
        this.arrayelem = (T[]) new Object[max];
        this.topo = -1;
    }
    public boolean estaCheia(){
      return this.topo == this.arrayelem.length-1;
    }
    public boolean estaVazia(){
        return this.topo == -1;
    }
    public boolean inserir(T elem){
        if(!this.estaCheia()){
            this.arrayelem[++ this.topo] = elem;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public T remover(){
        if(!this.estaVazia()){
           T aux = this.arrayelem[this.topo];
            this.topo--;
            return aux;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Queria entender a lógica, se é um palindromo ou não.

Comment: Não dá pra entender o que você quer fazer, e sim o código é necessário. Dá uma lida, na central de ajuda, nos itens da seção perguntando: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Já modifiquei o código

Comment: Palíndromo quer dizer que a string de trás pra frente é igual à própria string. Mas no seu caso, x e y não são palíndromos - na verdade uma é o inverso da outra. Vc quer verificar se são palíndromos ou se uma é inverso da outra?

Comment: Quero verificar se uma é o inverso da outra...Eu pensei que fossem Palindromos,mas não são,se puder me ajudar,ficarei super grato

Comment: Se for um exercício e vc é obrigado a usar pilha, é simples: empilhe os caracteres de x, depois vá desempilhando e comparando com os caracteres de y. Mas se não tiver que usar pilha, vc pode [inverter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116062/112052) x e comparar com y.

Comment: Terei que usar pilha...Então no caso,eu empilharia tudo antes,dentro de um loop,e depois eu desempilharia verificando..Seria isso?

Comment: Basicamente isso :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, isso não é palíndromo. Palíndromo é uma string que lendo do começo pro fim é igual a do fim pro começo. Exemplo (ignorando acentos e espaços):

> Socorram-me subi no ônibus em Marrocos

Dito isso, para verificar se y é o inverso de x você deve inverter x e verificar se é igual a y. Para fazer isso usando uma pilha, você coloca os caracteres de x na pilha. Depois monta uma string removendo os caracteres da pilha. Como numa pilha o último caracter que entrou é o primeiro a sair, a string resultante é o inverso da primeira. Daí é só comparar com y.

```
Pilha<Character> pilha = new Pilha<>(100);
String x = "ABABBA";
String y = "ABBABA";
String z = "ABBABB";

for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
    Character c = x.charAt(i);
    pilha.inserir(c);
}

String reversed = new String();
int i = 0;
while (!pilha.estaVazia()) {
    reversed += pilha.remover();
}

System.out.println("x é inverso de y? " + reversed.equals(y));
System.out.println("x é inverso de z? " + reversed.equals(z));
```

Comment: Muiiito obriagadooo,serio mesmo.Já estava desesperado kk.

Comment: Então aceita a resposta =) https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers