# Inverter string contendo números

Tags: java, string

Usando este código como teste, cujo objetivo é inverter uma string contendo números.

Input: `0123456789`

Output: `[57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48]`
 ao contrário de `[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]`.

```
public class exercise33 {

    public static void main(String[] agrs) {    


        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String hold = "";
        int j = 0;

        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        hold = sc.next();


        int[] test = new int[hold.length()];


        for(int i = hold.length() - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
            test[j++] = hold.charAt(i);
        }

        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(test));;

        sc.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso acontece porque você está lidando com **texto**, e não com números. Apesar do texto conter dígitos de 0 a 9, ainda sim são caracteres, e não valores numéricos.

Só que o `char`, apesar do nome, também é um tipo numérico. Então quando você pega um `char` retornado por [`charAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) e atribui a um `int`, este passa a ter o respectivo valor do caractere na [tabela ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/). Exemplo:

```
char c = '0';
System.out.println(c); // 0
int n = c;
System.out.println(n); // 48
System.out.println(c == 48); // true
```

Para fazer o que você precisa (transformar o caractere `0` no número 0, etc), basta subtrair 48, que é o valor do caractere `0`. Assim, cada `int` terá o seu valor correto (pois os valores são consecutivos, o caractere `1` possui o valor 49, o `2` é 50, etc):

```
for (int i = hold.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    test[j++] = hold.charAt(i) - 48;
}
```

Ou ainda:

```
for (int i = hold.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    test[j++] = hold.charAt(i) - '0';
}
```

---

Apenas para complementar, [existem formas melhores de se inverter uma string](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116062/112052).

Comment: Outra [forma](https://ideone.com/05VTrR) é, em vez de usar um array, usar uma string para receber o resultado: `test += hold.charAt(i);`