# Permitir somente letras, números e hífen

Tags: php, string, regex

Como validar uma string em php para que contenha **somente** letras, números e hífen ( - )

Obrigado

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar expressões regulares. A função [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php) retorna 1 se a string for válida, zero se não for válida e FALSE se ocorrer um erro.

Pra validar letras com acento, números e hífens:

```
preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9-]+$/u', 'lês-criolês-10');
```

Pra validar letras sem acento, números e hífens:

```
preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9-]+$/', 'teste-1-2-3');
```

Comment: `\w` = `a-zA-Z0-9_`, `\d` = `0-9`, porque colocar o `\d` de novo na expressão? Se ele não quiser o `_` não é 100% correto.

Comment: Tem toda razão @GuilhermeLautert. Editei minha resposta com um set mais explícito.

Answer (score 6):

#### Código

```
$pattern = '~^[[:alnum:]-]+$~u';

$str = 'teste-1';
vr((boolean) preg_match($pattern, $str)); // true

$str = 'teste_2';
vr((boolean) preg_match($pattern, $str)); // false

$str = 'maça';
vr((boolean) preg_match($pattern, $str)); // true
```

#### Explicação

`[:alnum:]` é uma [classe *POSIX*](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions#Character_classes) que engloba `[[:alpha:][:digit:]]`.

- `[:alpha:]` = a-zA-Z
- `[:digit:]` = 0-9

### Edição

Como sugerido pelo [@GuilhermeNascimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635/guilherme-nascimento), é importante saber para que se usa o modificador `u` no final das REGEX.

#### Unicode

Por padrão o PHP não da suporte a Unicode, realizando uma pesquisa por byte (8 bits). Contudo alguns caracteres não são representados apenas com 8 bits, como o caso do `ç` que é representado por 8 bits para o `c` + 8 bits para o `'`(acento) assim sua pesquisa retornaria `false`, pois ele não reconheceria o próximo byte no `ç`.
Ao utilizar o modificador `u` você esta ativando um pesquisa por caractere e não por byte, note que isso não quer disser que vai passar a considerar 2 bytes e sim "caractere completo".
Veja a conversão de alguns caracteres com [esta ferramente](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter), como por exemplo o `♫`, que é um caractere de 3 bytes.

[Pergunta relacionada.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81600/regex-operador-captura-de-meta-caracter)
[Artigo relacionado.](http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todo_Desenvolvedor_De_Software_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_Precisa_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_E_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_%28Sem_Desculpas!%29)

Comment: Cite também que o modificador `u` é pra uso do unicode, sem eles acentos não serão reconhecidos se forem utf8 por exemplo. Mas de resto é a melhor resposta +1

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Melhoria implementada :D

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
return preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$/', $string) ? true : false
```