# preg_match(...) para vários tipos de texto

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Como posso fazer a validação dos textos abaixo?

Letras (incluindo acentos) e números (sem espaçamentos), separados por . ou ,. ex: 'olá123'

Números inteiros e/ou décimas. ex: '22' ou '2.2'

Comment: resumindo: letras que contenham números e números em geral mesmo os fracionários. É isso?

Comment: É isso mesmo. Mas ambos sem espaços. Números fracionários  com , ou .

Comment: aceita café, chá, água?

Answer (score 4):

Em uma [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121084/14213) tenho uma [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/121145/14213) que pode ser de ajuda.

No seu caso esta um pouco vago, pois você não especifica se os numerais podem vir antes, depois, estar no meio, se pode ser misturado.

`~^(?=.*[[:alpha:]].*)([[:alpha:]]*(\d+([.,]\d+)?)?[[:alpha:]]*)*$~u`

[Esta REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/pO9tH7/1) vai aceitas todas as questões que coloquei acima.

- 123teste
- teste123
- teste123teste
- 123teste123
- t3st3

#### Explicação

- `([[:alpha:]]*(\d+([.,]\d+)?)?[[:alpha:]]*)*` - Esta parte libera para ter letras antes de depois dos dígitos, mas note que todos eles são opcionais, o que liberaria o `NADA`.
- `(?=.*[[:alpha:]].*)` - Esta parte garante que a `string` tenha ao menos um alpha.

Como já havia comentado em outra resposta.

- `[:alpha:]` = `[a-zA-Z]`, mas note que há uma diferença, como vou usar o modificador `u` de unicode, o ideal é usar o `[:alpha:]` pois vai incluir também caracteres acentuados.

Comment: mais uma para chegar ao 25k+ futebol club :) +1

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento kkk, algum dia :D

Answer (score 2):

Nada que uma boa [estudada sobre expressões regulares](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/) não resolva.

Somente a parte dos acentos que não inclui, mas o resta tá ok.

`[a-zA-Z]+(\d+((\.|,)\d+)?)`

#### [a-zA-Z]+

Casa com letras de a ate z ou de A ate Z com 1 ou mais ocorrências.

#### (\d+

Casa com 1 ou mais dígitos numéricos e inicia um grupo.

#### (.|,)

Apos os dígitos deve ter um .(ponto) ou uma ,(virgula), os parênteses são para agrupar um trecho.

#### \d+

Apos o ponto ou virgula, mais uma sequencia de dígitos

#### )?)

Fecha os 2 grupos que foram abertos antes, sendo o mais interno opcional.

É meio complicado descrever regex por texto, eu particularmente acho dificil de entender, ainda mais no começo.

Esse site [regexpal](http://www.regexpal.com/) serve para testar as regex, facilita bastante a vida.

Comment: Boa resposta, mas isto não trabalha com acentos, recomendo que revise ;)