# Regular Expression Regex

Tags: c#, regex

Quero fazer padrões dessa maneira:

```
[a-z]+[acentos] || [a-z]+[acentos]+[espaço]+[a-z]+[acentos] || [a-z]+[acentos]+[-]+[a-z]+[acentos]
```

Para que seja possível realizar o cadastro de uma palavra, é preciso estar dentro de um desses padrões.

Por exemplo:

```
téstê || téstê téstê || téstê-téstê
```

Eu fiz assim:

```
palavra = TextBox1.Text;
Regex regex;
string padrao = @"[^A-Za-záàâãéêíîóõôúûçÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÓÔÕÚÇ']";
regex = new Regex(padrao);
string palavra2 = regex.Replace(palavra, "");
if (palavra == palavra2)
{
    Label1.Text = "Ok!";
}
else {
    padrao = @"[^A-Za-záàâãéêíîóõôúûçÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÓÔÕÚÇ'] [^A-Za-záàâãéêíîóõôúûçÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÓÔÕÚÇ']";

    regex = new Regex(padrao);
    palavra2 = regex.Replace(palavra, "");
    if (palavra == palavra2)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Ok!";
    }
}
```

O primeiro padrão deu certo, pois tudo o que não é letra ou letras com acento é trocado por vazio. Armazeno essa troca numa nova string e comparo com a anterior, caso sejam iguais, a palavra seguiu o padrão. Se a primeira string houvesse um número por exemplo, a nova string (que é o padrão) seria sem o número, portanto a palavra não seguiu o padrão.

O problema está nos outros padrões. Eu fiz o teste e este:

```
 @"[^A-Za-záàâãéêíîóõôúûçÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÓÔÕÚÇ'] [^A-Za-záàâãéêíîóõôúûçÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÓÔÕÚÇ']";
```

Está aceitando começar com espaço. Mas deveria trocar o espaço que está no início, por vazio. O espaço só deveria ser permitido no meio. Eu não sei bem usar essas expressões. Acredito que alguém que saiba, vai saber me dizer como devo deixar a minha expressão.

Comment: Se fosse PHP você poderia fazer [assim](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/149644/preg-match-para-v%c3%a1rios-tipos-de-texto/149678#149678), mas pelo que vi, C# não tem um bom suporte a unicode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente usar essa expressão regular:

`[A-Za-zÀ-ú]+ ?\-?[A-Za-zÀ-ú]+`

Explicação do que eu coloquei a mais:

- `+` determina que o que vier imediatamente antes dele deve aparecer 1 ou mais
- `?` opcional
- `' '?` espaço não obrigatório
- `\-?` hífen não obrigatório

Veja funcionando no [Online Regex](https://regex101.com/r/nNDp5o/2).

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo, o "?" resolveu o problema. Só queria entender uma coisa. Essa expressão não obedece uma sequência? Por que ele aceitava espaço no início sendo que eu o coloquei no meio?

Comment: @HeyJoe, como assim "não obedece uma sequência?" Ela vai aceitar qualquer sequência que contenha letras com ou sem espaço e hífen.  
Se quiser que aceite espaço no início é só colocar \s no começo ou \s? No meio aceita por causa do \s? entre [A-Za-zÀ-ú]

Comment: Eu digo na minha expressão, não nessa sua. Naquela minha, eu coloquei o espaço entre os caracteres, mesmo assim ele dava match com um espaço no início, queria saber o por quê. Por isso perguntei se ele obedece ou não uma sequência.

Comment: Naquela minha expressão tudo o que não for letras ele deveria trocar por vazio, mas ele aceitava o espaço no início, isso que eu não entendi, ele não trocava o espaço no início, mas deveria...

Comment: @HeyJoe, achei que fosse na minha. Acho que na sua expressão aceitava espaço por que quando você acrescenta um ^ logo após o [ define classes que não contenham determinados caracteres. Por exemplo: [^a] reconhece qualquer caractere, exceto a.

Comment: Então, leia o meu comentário um segundo antes do seu rsrs veja o meu código lá em c#, tudo o que não for letras no início é trocado por vazio, ou seja, o espaço deveria ser trocado por vazio mas isso não aconteceu. O problema foi resolvido com o "?" e o "+" que você me passou.

Comment: @HeyJoe, aceita porque o espaço não é letra. Você colocou o ^, [^A-Za-záàâãéêíîóõôúûçÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÓÔÕÚÇ'], ou seja, vai dar math em tudo que não for letra. Olha ai: https://regex101.com/r/MWlmqD/2

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46431/discussion-between-heyjoe-and-taisbevalle).

Comment: Obrigado, não entendo muito ainda o comportamento dessas expressões, mas usando o site que você me passou https://regex101.com/r/MWlmqD/2 deu pra entender melhor.

Comment: "\s? **espaço** não obrigatório"? Recomendo a leitura [O que significa o atalho \s nas REGEX?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110701/14213)

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert, o "A classe \s é equivalente à classe [ \t\n\x0B\f\r]"

Comment: @Taisbevalle chegou a  ver link que mandei? Por via de evitar problemas se o que você esta buscando é **espaço** então deve se usar **espaço** e não `\s`.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert, vi o link sim.