# Regex - Pegar texto até determinada sequência de caracteres

Tags: regex

Gostaria de pegar o texto até os caracteres `a)` e se possível e as respostas separadas também usando Regex?

```
pergunta pergunta pergunta pergunta pergunta pergunta pergunta pergunta pergunta pergunta pergunta pergunta pergunta pergunta pergunta<br /><br />

pergunta pergunta pergunta pergunta pergunta pergunta pergunta pergunta pergunta pergunta pergunta pergunta pergunta pergunta pergunta<br /><br />

  a) resposta a<br />
  b) resposta b<br />
  c) resposta c<br />
  d) resposta d<br />
  e) resposta e<br />
```

Estou conseguindo pegar as respostas com essa regra simples http://regexr.com/3hb4p mas a pergunta tá dificil. Lembrando que a pergunta pode possuir vários parágrafos.

Comment: Usa alguma linguagem de programação? vc quer pegar só a pergunta? ou quer pegar a pergunta e as respostas separadas?

Comment: @RodneyMendonça já alterei para que fiquem em linhas diferentes

Comment: Pode ser só a expressão regular mesmo. o resto me viro aqui.

Comment: Se eu conseguir separar a pergunta das respostas já consigo cadastrar no banco separadamente.

Comment: Mas só terá uma pergunta nessa string, ou terá mais?

Comment: Uso asp 3 mas só necessito da ER. Quero pegar a pergunta e as respostas separadas. Acredito que terei que fazer 6 regex. Uma para pergunta e outras 5 para as respostas. Acredito que a pergunta teria que fazer alguma regra que pega o texto até o a) que é o início da primeira resposta.

Comment: com isso já conseguiria pegar as respostas, já que o processo seria o mesmo.

Comment: não tô conseguindo limitar a pergunta até o a)

Comment: só terá uma pergunta. coloquei em dois parágrafos pra representar a quebra de linha. @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: tente o seguinte   /(.*?a\))/s https://regex101.com/r/okE9nz/3

Comment: show @CaiqueRomero perfeito. sem querer abusar e pra pegar as respostas individualmente?

Comment: Questões: 1. Essa é a real formatação do arquivo? (com esses espaços entre as perguntas e no inicio de cada resposta) 2. Essa `pergunta` é só uma analogia para um pergunta real correto? Então poderia ser de teor matemático correto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use essa regex:

```
((.|\n)*?)(a\).*?)\n*?(b\).*?)\n*?(c\).*?)\n*?(d\).*?)\n*?(e\).*?)$|\n*?
```

Ela irá separar o texto em grupos sendo que:

- Grupo 1 - Contém o texto antes da opção `a)`.
- Grupo 2 - Não captura nada, porém encapsula as opções de captura do grupo 1.
- Grupo 3 - Contém o conteúdo da opção `a` até a quebra de linha (onde começaria a opção b no seu exemplo).
- Grupo 4 - Contém o conteúdo da opção `b` até a quebra de linha.
- Grupo 5 - Contém o conteúdo da opção `c` até a quebra de linha.
- Grupo 6 - Contém o conteúdo da opção `d` até a quebra de linha.
- Grupo 7 - Contém o conteúdo da opção `e` até a quebra de linha ou fim do texto.

[Você pode ver o funcionamento dessa regex aqui](https://regex101.com/r/fn1d7g/3)

**Explicação da regex**

`((.|\n)*?)` - Vai capturar qualquer caractere e quebra de linha do conteúdo até que chegue o primeiro delimitador.

`(a\).*?)\n*?` - `a\)` é igual a `a)` e ele será usado como um delimitador, para que o primeiro grupo de captura pare de capturar na primeira ocorrência da sequencia `a)`, após isso a regex irá capturar todo o conteúdo até a primeira quebra de linha.

`(b\).*?)\n*?` - O funcionamento desse grupo de captura é igual ao do grupo 3, só que captura a partir do `b)`.

`(c\).*?)\n*?` - O funcionamento desse grupo de captura é igual ao do grupo 3, só que captura a partir do `c)`.

`(d\).*?)\n*?` - O funcionamento desse grupo de captura é igual ao do grupo 3, só que captura a partir do `d)`.

`(e\).*?)\$|\n*?` - O funcionamento desse grupo de captura é igual ao do grupo 3, só que captura a partir do `e)`e para no fim do texto ou em uma quebra de linha, pro caso de você usar essa regex em um arquivo que possua muitas questões e textos.

Comment: acho que foi quase lá. a pergunta tá passando nas respostas. gostaria que pegasse até o a).

Comment: as respostas se houver quebra de linha não pega essa quebra.

Comment: perfeito cara. Agradeço muito. Vou pegar esse código e ver se consigo montar o que quero.

Comment: @Rod atualizado para funcionar do jeito que você queria.

Comment: Obrigado meu amigo.

Comment: analisando esse código novamente, é o mais claro que vi até agora sobre o que quero. Tem ajeitar ele para eliminar os BRS só do fim de cada grupo?

Answer (score 13):

**Casar pergunta e respostas com uma expressão**

Se você quiser realmente casar ***qualquer coisa*** até uma letra seguida por um `)`, ou o fim da string, pode usar esta RegExp:   <sub><sup>[(regexr.com)](https://regexr.com/3hc6e)</sup></sub>

```
([\s\S]+?(?=\b[a-z][)]|$))
```

- `[\s\S]` é uma maneira de casar todos os caracteres, incluindo quebras de linha.
  <sub>*Normalmente, usaríamos a flag* singleline *para alterar o comportamento do ponto, mas não existe no ASP.*</sub>
- `(?=`…`)` é um lookahead (dá uma "espiada" adiante), garantindo que foi seguido por uma letra e um `)`, ou pelo final da string. Mas tem a peculiaridade de corresponder ao padrão, enquanto não faz parte do fragmento casado.
- `\b` é uma borda de palavra.

No entanto, essa expressão não é muito eficiente, especialmente com textos longos, e pode dar um falso positivo com casos como:
`"pergunta (veja o segmento b) pergunta"`.

Tendo em conta que cada resposta é **precedida por (pelo menos) uma quebra de linha**, pode usá-lo como uma condição adicional. Desta forma, podemos combinar linhas inteiras, desde que uma linha *interna* não comece com
`[a-z][)]`.

Regex:   <sub><sup>[(regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/tuKr3C/4)</sup></sub>

```
[^\r\n]+(?:\r?\n(?!\s*[a-z][)])[^\r\n]*)*
```

Explicação:

[image: Debuggex.com]

- `[^\r\n]+` ≝ Toda uma linha.
- `(?:\n(?!\s*[a-z][)]).*)*` ≝ Grupo sem captura, para repetir este subpadrão (0-infinito):

  - `\r?\n` ≝ Uma quebra de linha.
  - `(?!\s*[a-z][)])` ≝ Negative lookahead, garantindo que não seja seguido por uma letra e um `)` (com possíveis espaços desde o início da linha até a letra).
  - `[^\r\n]*` ≝ Toda uma linha.

Sendo que está usando ASP:

```vb
Dim texto
texto = "Os Embargos de Terceiros fazem parte do procedimento especial, previsto no Código de Processo Civil," & _
        " sendo possível sua utilização por quem, não sendo parte no processo, sofre constrição ou sofre" & _
        " ameaça de constrição sobre bens que possua ou sobre os quais tenha direito incompatível com o ato constritivo." & _ 
        " Sobre o ajuizamento dos embargos, assinale a alternativa INCORRETA." & vbNewline & _
        "" & vbNewline & _
        "Considere o segmento â€œ[...] o Estado só percebe o eco enfraquecido.â€ (2º§). Pode-se afirmar que" & _
        " a partir do recurso de linguagem utilizado pelo enunciador na escolha da palavra â€œEstadoâ€, identifica-se 7" & vbNewline & _
        "" & vbNewline & _
        "a) o estabelecimento de uma comparação entre â€œEstadoâ€ e â€œgovernantesâ€." & vbNewline & _
        "b) o emprego de uma palavra redundante objetivando reforçar a ideia expressa." & vbNewline & _
        " questões que irão ter várias quebra de linhas" & vbNewline & _
        "" & vbNewline & _
        "" & vbNewline & _
        " questões que irão ter várias quebra de linhas" & vbNewline & _
        "c) uma transferência de percepções resultando em uma fusão de impressões sensoriais." & vbNewline & _
        "d) a evocação de um termo em lugar de uma palavra, com a qual se acha relacionada não sendo sinônimos. "
```

```vb
Set re = New RegExp
re.Global = true  'casar todas as coincidências
re.Pattern = "[^\r\n]+(?:\r?\n(?!\s*[a-z][)])[^\r\n]*)*"

'corresponder com a regex
Set matches = re.Execute(texto)
If (matches.Count) Then
    'a primeira é a pergunta <- matches(0)
    Response.Write("Pergunta === " & matches(0))

    'o resto são as respostas <- matches(m)
    For m = 1 To matches.Count - 1
        Response.Write(vbNewline & "Resposta " & m & " === ")
        Response.Write(matches(m))
    Next
End If

Set matches = Nothing
Set re = Nothing
```

Resultado:

```
Pergunta === Os Embargos de Terceiros fazem parte do procedimento especial, previsto no Código de Processo Civil, sendo possível sua utilização por quem, não sendo parte no processo, sofre constrição ou sofre ameaça de constrição sobre bens que possua ou sobre os quais tenha direito incompatível com o ato constritivo. Sobre o ajuizamento dos embargos, assinale a alternativa INCORRETA.

Considere o segmento â€œ[...] o Estado só percebe o eco enfraquecido.â€ (2º§). Pode-se afirmar que a partir do recurso de linguagem utilizado pelo enunciador na escolha da palavra â€œEstadoâ€, identifica-se 7
Resposta 1 === a) o estabelecimento de uma comparação entre â€œEstadoâ€ e â€œgovernantesâ€.
Resposta 2 === b) o emprego de uma palavra redundante objetivando reforçar a ideia expressa.
 questões que irão ter várias quebra de linhas


 questões que irão ter várias quebra de linhas
Resposta 3 === c) uma transferência de percepções resultando em uma fusão de impressões sensoriais.
Resposta 4 === d) a evocação de um termo em lugar de uma palavra, com a qual se acha relacionada não sendo sinônimos.
```

Carreguei num hospedagem grátis se quiser testá-lo:
[http://mariano.somee.com/258904/index.asp](http://mariano.somee.com/258904/)

Answer (score 9):

Você pode utilizar [`/(.*?a\))/s`](https://regex101.com/r/okE9nz/3) para obter todos os caracteres incluindo **a)**

Você pode utilizar [`/(.*?)a\)/s`](https://regex101.com/r/okE9nz/4) para todos caracteres anteriores a **a)**

Explicação:

`.*?`  Identifica todos caracteres

`a`    Identifica um `a` literalmente (diferencia maiúscula de minúscula)

`\(`   Identifica o primeiro parênteses

Comment: perfeito. obrigado.

Comment: Você também pode, no lugar de alterar a "glutonice" do operador `*`, pedir para casar com "não-a": `/([^a]*a)/` para incluir o primeiro `a`, e `/([^a]*)a/` para excluir o primeiro `a`

Comment: @Mariano, tem razão, falei bobeira... não tinha prestado atenção que era até `a)`. Quando havia lido a resposta (e também o título da pergunta me levou a esse erro) entendi que era até o caracter `a`. Para fazer essa alternativa sem usar o `.*?` é necessário um pouco mais do que apenas a lista negada. `(([^a]|a[^)])*)a\)` creio ser a alternativa excluindo `a)` da seleção

Comment: @Mariano : https://regex101.com/r/rq8IwI/1

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado O problema é que o ponto não coincide com quebras de linha, então `.*?`deve ser trocado para `[\s\S]*?` (pode ler [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/259001/53463))... Seu regex tem um problema teórico, [se `a)` for precedido por outro `a`](https://regex101.com/r/rq8IwI/2)... Mas se você quer o mais performatico, é "[unrolling the loop](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop)": [`[^a]*(?:a(?!\))[^a]*)*`](https://regex101.com/r/rq8IwI/3)

Answer (score 4):

Caso você esteja usando uma biblioteca com mais recursos como [PCRE](https://www.regular-expressions.info/pcre.html).

Poderia usar :

```
/(?(?=\s+)|(?(?=\w\))(?<a>\w\).*)|(?<q>.*?\n)))/g
```

Veja funcionando no [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/icgb3P/4)

Aqui estou usando ["condicionais"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) e ["grupos nominais"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html)

#### Explicação

- `(?(?=\s+)|...)` - Este condicional basicamente diz de deve ignorar ["espaços"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/110702/14213), pois caso encontre a primeira condição é "fazer nada".
- `(?(?=\w\))` - Aqui de fato temos a condição para perguntas e respostas, pois caso encontre `[a-z0-9_]` seguido de `)` é resposta, se não, é uma pergunta.

#### Nota

- Eu usei `\w` para facilitar, o correto creio seria [`[[:alpha:]]`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/149678/14213), ou caso use o modificador `i` simplifica para `[a-z]`

#### Problemas

- Essa Regex acaba gerando muito lixo pelo fato da não capturar da primeira condição.

Comment: Detalhe: acho que você poderia usar `.*` em vez de `.*?\n`... E há um benefício usando as condicionais em vez de [`\s+|(?<a>\w\).*)|(?<q>.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/HJjC98/2)?

Comment: @Mariano de fato a segunda condicional não é necessária, mas ainda manteria a primeira para não gerar capturar com todos aqueles espaços, ate mesmo facilitando no processo de remoção destes índices. [`(?(?=\s+)|(?:(\w\).*)|(.*?\n)))`](https://regex101.com/r/icgb3P/5)

Comment: Entendo, embora seja questão de ver se há algum grupo capturado ... Ou usar [`(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`](https://regex101.com/r/HJjC98/3) no PCRE ;-)

Comment: @Mariano muito interessante, não tinha visto estas diretivas ainda, tenho que ler um pouco mais :D

Comment: http://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html é o que melhor explica