# Problemas com PHP expressões regulares?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Tô pegando um arquivo `.txt` e tirando as letras e linhas em branco. Tá dando problema com o carácter especial `\t` ou `\s` ele não reconhece.

O código abaixo:

```
<?php

function pass1() {
    $treat = fopen ("C:\\Users\\Bridge\\Downloads\\D_lotfac\\lott.txt", "r+w+");
    $treat1 = fopen ("C:\\Users\\Bridge\\Downloads\\D_lotfac\\lott1.txt", "r+w+");

    while (!feof ($treat)) {
        $linha = fgets($treat,4096);
        $patterns = array();
        $patterns [0] = '/[(A-Z)i]*/';
        $patterns [1] = '/Â|Ã|Á|À|É|Ê|Í|Î|Ç|Ó|Õ|Ô|Ö|Ú|Û|Ü/';
        $patterns [2] ='/ã|â|à|á|é|ê|í|î|ç|ó|ô|ô|ö|ú|û|ü/';
        $patterns [3] = '/\t/';                 
        $patterns [4] = '/[(a-z)i]*/';
        $patterns [5] = '   ';

        $replacements = array();
        $replacements[] = '';
        $linha = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $linha);
        fwrite ($treat1, $linha); 

        printf($linha . "<br>");
        }
}
```

Tá gerando o arquivo `lott1.txt` corretamente, só que os `tabs` não estão sendo retirados nem os espaços (`2x`, `3x`, etc ). Já coloquei o tab literalmente "   " ou coloquei `\t` dentro do array `$pattern[]`. Não elimina.

Qual o problema?

Comment: use uma única `pattern`, a `\w`, ela aceita todos os caracteres exceto os especiais

Comment: ja tentou mudar o tab para `/\t+/`

Comment: @user6855041 coloque um antes e depois do arquivo, isso pode ajudar mais a entender a sua duvida?

Comment: para espaços, use `/\s+/` (1 ou mais ocorrências) , `/\s{5}/` (5 ocorrências)

Comment: @lucasvscn Recomendo que leia [O que significa o atalho \s nas REGEX?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110701/14213)

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert obrigado pela indicação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Primeiramente

> `\s` **Não é "espaço"!!**

Você pode ver o que significa o `\s` [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110701/14213).

#### Problema

- Pelo que eu notei você também deseja capturar caracteres acentuados. Para isso uso o modificados `u`, abordado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/121145/14213).
- Para capturar tanto maiúsculas quanto minusculas pode usar `[a-zA-Z]`, `[[:alpha:]]` ou `[a-z]` com modificador `i`.
- Se seu intuito é remover todos *tabs* e espaços pode fazer assim `[\t ]+`.

#### Solução

Em resumo seu *pattern* seria :

`~[a-z\t ]+~iu`

#### Nota

- `[(A-Z)i]` - se seu intuito era montar um grupo com `A-Z` isso não ocorre dentro do `[`...`]`, sendo os parenteses interpretados literalmente.