# Expressão regular para selecionar palavra inteira e case sensitive em palavra acentuada

Tags: java, regex

Preciso fazer um programa que pesquise uma determinada palavra em um conjunto de textos e grife a palavra pesquisada no meio do texto.

Para isso desenvolvi o seguinte método:

```
 public void grifarTexto(Relato relato, String texto) {
    relato.setDescricaoRelato(relato.getDescricaoRelato().replaceAll("(?i)("
 + texto + ")", "<mark>$1</mark>"));
 }
```

Porém ai surgiram dois probleminhas...

1º Gostaria que ele pegasse a palavra inteira, porém quando colocos os caracteres de marcação de inicio (^) e fim ($), ele acaba não grifando nenhuma parte do texto.

Método utilizado:

```
 public void grifarTexto(Relato relato, String texto) {
    relato.setDescricaoRelato(relato.getDescricaoRelato().replaceAll("(?i)
 ^(" + texto + ")$", "<mark>$1</mark>")); 
 }
```

2º Ele está ignorando os caracteres maísculo e minusco das palavra corretamente, salvo quando tem acento.
Por exemplo: Quando pesquiso pela palavra mão

```
MÃO (não grifa)
mão (grifa)
mÃo (não grifa)
MãO (grifa)
```

Ou seja ele não ignora os caracteres maísculo e minusco de letras acentuadas.

Fiz testes dessas expressões no site Rubular para ver se estavam corretas e pelo retorno do site aparenta estar ok.
Links com os testes: http://rubular.com/r/YRcTJBn8eY e http://rubular.com/r/dh753n4mgl

Alguém sabe qual a expressão regular que eu devo usar para conseguir fazer as validações que eu desejo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você esta trabalhando com pesquisa de palavras em texto os delimitadores de pesquisa de palavra não são os `^` (inicio), `$` fim, pois estes se referem a *string* inteira.

- `^` - inicio da *string*
- `$` - fim da *string*

Para resolver esta caso [usa o `\b` (boundary)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110874/14213), que ser para palavras.

Quanto as palavras acentuadas, o problema é que assim como o [PHP e Java usa a tabela ASCII simples](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/121145/14213) para tratar as pesquisa ou seja se limitando as 127 primeiras posições da tabela.

Para resolver este problema necessita usa o modificador :

`Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`

Você poderia fazer algo assim

`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b"+texto+"\\b", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);`

Answer (score 0):

**RESOLVIDO**

Muito obrigado Guilherme, deu certo!!!

Único detalhe é que acabei fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
relato.setDescricaoRelato(relato.getDescricaoRelato().replaceAll("(?i)(?u)(\\b" + texto + "\\b)", "<mark>$1</mark>"));
```

Comment: se ele te ajudou a resolver, deveria marcar a resposta dele como correta

Comment: Sorry... Feito!!

Comment: boa @BrenoCabral